# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in - Cual es el error?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buenas para todos, tengo un inconveniente con este error, soy principiante he buscado y no he encontrado solución. Se trata de un formulario de citas y la base de datos esta en phpMyAdmin, este formulario es para atender una cita entonces Primero se listan solo las citas cuyo estado sea Asignado.:

```
<?php  
require "ConexionDatos.php";
$objConexion=Conectarse();
$sql="select ci.idCita, ci.cit_fecha, ci.cit_hora, p.pac_nombres,     

p.pac_apellidos, m.med_nombres, m.med_apellidos, m.med_especialidad,  

c.con_nombre, ci.cit_estado, ci.cit_observaciones
from pacientes p, medicos m, consultorios c, citas ci
where (p.id_paciente=ci.cit_paciente)and
(m.idMedico=ci.cit_medico) and
(c.idConsultorio=ci.cit_consultorio) and
(ci.cit_estado='Asignado')";

$resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);
?>
<h1 align="center">LISTADO CITAS</h1>
<table width="90%" border="1" align="center">
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#99ff66" class="texto">
<td>Fecha</td>
<td>Hora</td>
<td>Paciente</td>
<td>Medico</td>
<td>Consultorio</td>
<td>Estado</td>
<td>Obervaciones</td>
<td>Atender</td>
</tr>
<?php 
while ($citas=$resultado->fetch_object())
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $citas->cit_fecha ?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->cit_hora ?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->pac_nombres." ".$citas->pac_apellidos?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->med_nombres." " .$citas->med_apellidos?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->con_nombre ?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->cit_estado ?></td>
<td><?php echo $citas->cit_observaciones ?></td>


<td align="center">
<a href="frmEditarCita.php?idCita= <?php echo $citas->idCita ?>" title="clic para atender la cita"> 
<img src="../img/editar.png" width="62" height="51" border="0"    align="middle" /></a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}// cerramos ciclo while
?>
</table>
```

Este es el codigo que me lleva al formulario para editar la cita:

```
<?php 
require "ConexionDatos.php";

//se hace la consulta de acuerdo al idCita que llega
$objConexion=Conectarse();
$sql="select p.pac_nombres, p.pac_apellidos, c.cit_observaciones
from pacientes p, citas c
where (p.idPaciente=c.cit_paciente) and
(c.idCita='$_REQUEST[$idCita]')";

$resultadoCitas=$objConexion->query($sql);
$cita=$resultadoCitas->fetch_object();  
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="actualizarCita.php">
<table width="43%" border="0" align="center" >
<tr bgcolor="#99ff66" class="texto">
<td colspan="2" align="center">ATENDER CITA</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="33%" align="right" bgcolor="#99ff66">Paciente:</td>
<td width="67%"><label for="paciente"></label>
<input name="paciente" type="text" id="paciente" readonly="readonly"                                             

size="60" value="<?php echo $cita->pac_nombres." ".$cita->pac_apellidos ?  

>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#99ff66">Observacione</td>
<td><label for="observaciones"></label>
<textarea name="observaciones" id="observaciones" cols="50" rows="10"
required="required"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#99ff66" class="texto">
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button"  

id="button" value="enviar"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
/*se inserta un campo oculto y le asigno el valor de idCita para pasarlo con el formulario. el idCita llega a este formulario*/
<input name="idCita" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['idCita']? 

>"/>
</form>
```

El otro código de archvio para validar la cita:

```
<?php 
require "ConexionDatos.php";
extract ($_REQUEST);

$objConexion=Conectarse();
$sql="update citas set       
cit_observaciones='$_REQUEST[observaciones]',cit_estado='Atendido'
where idCita='$_REQUEST[idCita]'";
$resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);

if ($resultado) {
header("location:listarCitas.php?x=1");// x=1 se actualizo correctamente
}
else{
header("location:listarCitas.php?x=2");// x=2 problemas actualizar la cita
$objConexion->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: El error que recibes es porque hay un error en la sentencia y entonces `query` devuelve `false`. Prueba a mostrar el valor de la variable `$sql` e intenta ejecutar esa sentencia directamente en PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Gracias por responder, como digo soy novato yo he intentado lo que me comentas pero como hago para colocar el $_REQUEST en PHPMyAdmin?.  por que quiero es el dato ingresado por el usuario se modifique la cita.

Comment: Haz `echo $sql;exit();` justo antes de la línea `$resultadoCitas=$objConexion->query($sql);`. Eso hará que se muestre la sentencia SQL y pare la ejecución del script. Entonces copia ese SQL y pégalo aquí o pruébalo directamente en PHPMyAdmin porque es la sentencia que se ejecutará

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro inserte el codigo    $sql;exit()  y me sale esto   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\CentroMedico\Citas\frmEditarCita.php on line 44

Comment: Antes de ese mensaje de error, ¿te aparece el SQL de la consulta? Puedes quitar el `exit()` lo que te interesa es la consulta en sí

Comment: Si, ya lo he reaizado y me sale esto: Notice: Undefined variable: idCita in C:\xampp\htdocs\CentroMedico\Citas\frmEditarCita.php on line 10. otice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\CentroMedico\Citas\frmEditarCita.php on line 10
select p.pac_nombres, p.pac_apellidos, c.cit_observaciones from pacientes p, citas c where (p.idPaciente=c.cit_paciente) and (c.idCita='')
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\CentroMedico\Citas\frmEditarCita.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: Pues ese es el problema. No has definido la variable `$idcita` en ningún lugar y luego la usas, eso hace que la consulta que se genera sea incorrecta. ¿Qué valor esperabas que tuviese?

Comment: me equivoque lo coloque ahi para probar si funcionaba, pero el codigo es:     `$sql="select p.pac_nombres, p.pac_apellidos, c.cit_observaciones
from pacientes p, citas c
where (p.idPaciente=c.cit_paciente) and
(c.idCita='$_REQUEST[idCita]')";` y el del formulario es esta parte: `<input name="idCita" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['idCita']?>"/>` Fijate en el primero formulario que envie.

Comment: Entonces el problema son las comillas, deberías ser `$_REQUEST['idCita']` como indico en la respuesta de abajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que recibes es porque hay un error en la sentencia y entonces `query` devuelve `false`. El valor `false` (booleano) no tiene ningún método/función llamado `fetch_object()` que es el error mostrado.

Como mencionas [en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10674/uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-object-on-boolean-in-cual-es?noredirect=1#comment18442_10674), el problema está en que la variable `$idCita` no está definida. En lugar de

```
(c.idCita='$_REQUEST[$idCita]')
```

Deberías hacer

```
(c.idCita='" . $_REQUEST['idCita'] . "')";
```

Porque ese es el nombre del `input` en tu formulario.

> NOTA: como bien indica aldanux en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10675/250). Tu código puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, deberías usar sentencias preparadas. Puedes leer más sobre inyección SQL en esta [otra pregunta de SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla).

Comment: Gracias, hago tal como me comentas y me sigue saliendo el mismo error que ingrese en la pregunta más esta: **Notice: Undefined index: idCita in C:\xampp\htdocs\CentroMedico\Citas\frmEditarCita.php on line 10**

Comment: @Juanzu Ok, si no es idCita, ¿cuál es el nombre de la variable?¿Qué variables pasas a esa página?  Si no te funciona ahí, tampoco te va a funcionar en el `input` que hay más abajo

Comment: Pues esa es la variable que esta en la base de datos, la verdad no se que sucede, gracias igualmente he aprendido cositas.

Comment: $_REQUEST no viene de la base de datos, viene de otra página o de una cookie. ¿Cómo llegas a la página donde recibes el error?

Comment: Si viene de la base de datos, viene de un formulario donde dando clic en una cita especifica que esta actualmente en atender y me lleva a este formulario para colocar la cita atendido.

Comment: @Juanzu ¿cuál es el `name` del campo que tiene el id de la cita en el primer formulario?

Comment: @AlavaroMontoro Ya escribir el otro código para que lo mires, gracias.