# No anda el envio de la consulta sql desde eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo este código que es el formulario de mi ventana para ingresar un mozo a una base de datos que esta creada desde `wamp`.

El problema es que no me envía la consulta, la conexión parece estar bien

Les dejo el código por aquí

```
package Ventanas;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import Clases.BaseDatos;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

public class ingresoMozo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private BaseDatos Palomos=null;
    private JTextField txtCed;
    private JTextField txtNom;
    private JTextField txtApe;

    private JTextField txtSueldo;
    private JTextField txtTel;
    private BaseDatos coco;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ingresoMozo frame = new ingresoMozo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ingresoMozo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 650, 650);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCedula = new JLabel("C\u00E9dula");
        lblCedula.setBounds(23, 99, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblCedula);

        JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
        lblNombre.setBounds(23, 124, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNombre);

        JLabel lblApellido = new JLabel("Apellido");
        lblApellido.setBounds(23, 150, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblApellido);

        JLabel lblTelfono = new JLabel("Tel\u00E9fono");
        lblTelfono.setBounds(23, 176, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblTelfono);

        JLabel lblMozoAadidoCorrectamenteerror = new JLabel("Mozo a\u00F1adido correctamente/error");
        lblMozoAadidoCorrectamenteerror.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblMozoAadidoCorrectamenteerror.setBounds(23, 239, 219, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblMozoAadidoCorrectamenteerror);

        JLabel lblIngresarMozo = new JLabel("Datos de mozo");
        lblIngresarMozo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblIngresarMozo.setBounds(49, 52, 112, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblIngresarMozo);

        JLabel lblIngresoDeMozo = new JLabel("Ingreso de mozo");
        lblIngresoDeMozo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblIngresoDeMozo.setBounds(260, 11, 160, 28);
        contentPane.add(lblIngresoDeMozo);

        txtCed = new JTextField();
        txtCed.setBounds(78, 100, 129, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtCed);
        txtCed.setColumns(10);

        txtNom = new JTextField();
        txtNom.setBounds(78, 125, 129, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtNom);
        txtNom.setColumns(10);

        txtApe = new JTextField();
        txtApe.setBounds(78, 150, 129, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtApe);
        txtApe.setColumns(10);

        String cedula, telefono;
        String nombre, apellido;
        nombre=txtNom.getText().toString();
        apellido=txtApe.getText().toString();
        cedula=txtCed.getText().toString();
        Integer ced=Integer.parseInt(cedula);
        telefono=txtTel.getText().toString();
        Integer tel=Integer.parseInt(telefono);

        String consulta1 = "INSERT INTO 'personas'('nombre', 'apellido', 'telefono', 'ci') VALUES ('" + nombre + "', '" + apellido + "' ,'" + tel + "', '" + ced + "');";


        JButton btnAceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
        btnAceptar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {



                    coco.ejecutar(consulta1);




        }});


        btnAceptar.setBounds(104, 285, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAceptar);

        JButton btnLimpiarDatos = new JButton("Limpiar datos");
        btnLimpiarDatos.setBounds(260, 285, 112, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLimpiarDatos);

        JLabel lblSueldo = new JLabel("Sueldo");
        lblSueldo.setBounds(23, 201, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSueldo);

        txtSueldo = new JTextField();
        txtSueldo.setBounds(78, 198, 129, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtSueldo);
        txtSueldo.setColumns(10);

        txtTel = new JTextField();
        txtTel.setBounds(75, 173, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtTel);
        txtTel.setColumns(10);

    }
}
```

Les dejo mi clase de Base de datos que tengo la conexion y la funcion para ejecutar una consulta

```
public Connection getConexion() {
    return conexion;
}    

public void setConexion(Connection conexion) {
        this.conexion = conexion;
} 

public boolean ejecutar(String sql) {
    try {
        Statement sentencia = getConexion().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
        sentencia.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }     
    return true;
}
```

El error que me aparece en pantalla es

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at Ventanas.ingresoMozo.(ingresoMozo.java:144)
>       at Ventanas.Indice$1.mouseClicked(Indice.java:53)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hola @Facundo deberias poner el tambien los logs o errores que se muestran. Mirate este link para mejorar tu pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos y mil disculpas por los errores de redacción.

Comment: ¿Y si lo haces a lo guarro con un import * a ver qué te sale?

Comment: Me sigue devolviendo el mismo error que tengo planteado en el post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es del codigo Java y no del insert en tu base de datos... el Logcat claramente dice :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at Ventanas.ingresoMozo.(ingresoMozo.java:144)

Esto quiere decir que en algun lugar de tu codigo (especificamente linea 144) estas haciendo un `Integer.parseInt` incorrecto

```
try{
   int numTelefono = Integer.parseInt(telefono);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 
   System.out.println("Los datos que ingresaste a telefono son incorrectos...");
}
```

Debes verificar bien tu tipo de datos que tienes para tus campos, veo un `telefono` y `cedula`, estos campos generalmente se configuran como `varchar` (en BD) y/o `string` (En codigo)  ya que sus valores no son aptos para cálculos matemáticos, si no que son para identificar y diferenciar de unos con otros....

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a escribir la consulta con comillas simples en vez de con apóstrofe:

```
String consulta1 = "INSERT INTO 'personas'('nombre', 'apellido', 'telefono', 'ci') VALUES ('" + nombre + "', '" + apellido + "' ,'" + tel + "', '" + ced + "');";
```

Comment: me dice error null0 desde el catch de exception me dice se ha encontrado este error: null0 por lo menos ahora me entra a los catchs y me dice algo antes me saltaban muchisimas lineas en rojo de consola

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que los valores estén asignados y no sean cadenas vacías? Podrías tener alguna restricción en tu definición de tabla. Me huele a fallo de parseo en los valores `ced` o `tel`

Comment: Soy estudiante recién empece hace poco y no encontrado otra manera de pasar el valor de String a int sin ser el Integer, ¿hay alguna otra manera?, lo que tu me dices es que no se esta convirtiendo bien el valor a int ¿verdad?

Comment: ¿Puedes decirme cuál es exactamente la línea 144 de `Ventanas.ingresoMozo`?

Answer (score 0):

Según el stack trace que tienes, parece que tu error viene de aquí:

```
cedula=txtCed.getText().toString();
Integer ced=Integer.parseInt(cedula); // <-- aquí
telefono=txtTel.getText().toString();
Integer tel=Integer.parseInt(telefono); // <-- o aquí
```

Puedes identificar más precisamente cuál de las 2 es al examinar más cuidadosamente el stack trace y ver cuál es la línea 144:

> Ventanas.ingresoMozo.(ingresoMozo.java:144) at

Como el mensaje de error dice:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

...aparentemente el valor de `cedula` o `telefono` es un string vacío, por lo que no puede convertirlo en un entero.

Te va a tocar manejar ese caso especial para evitar el error.

De paso, ya que veo que estás concatenando los valores directamente en tu SQL, te sugiero repasar la información siguiente: [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/18951)