# ¿Cómo insertar en dos tablas que comparten una llave foránea?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Tengo dos tablas `personas` y `mediciones`. `idPersona` es la llave primaria de `personas`. Y `mediciones` está relacionada a esta con `idPersona`. Estoy haciendo una carga masiva desde excel y los datos deben insertarse en estas dos tablas.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(.......);
conn.Open();

string query = "Insert into personaFisica (curp,nombre,apellidoPaterno,apellidoMaterno,fechaNacimiento,idGenero,idEscolaridad,idEstatusEscolaridad,idNivelMarginacion,idEstado,anio,mes)";
query += "values('" + columns[0] + "','" + columns[1] + "','" + columns[2] + "','" + columns[3] + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(columns[4]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + columns[5] + "','" + columns[6] + "','" + columns[7] + "','" + columns[8] + "','" + columns[9] + "','" + columns[10] + "','" + columns[11]+ "')";


query += "Insert into diagnosticoFisico (idPersona,activacion,medicion,presionSistolica,presionDiastolica,pulsoEnReposo,pulsoEnEsfuerzo,tiempo,consumoOxigeno,peso,estatura,cadera,cintura,porcentajeGraso,abdominales,lagartijas)";
query += "values( '" + columns[12] + "','" + columns[13] + "','" + columns[14] + "','" + columns[15] + "','" + columns[16] + "','" + columns[17] + "','" + columns[18] + "','" + columns[19] + "','" + columns[20] + "','" + columns[21] + "','" + columns[22] + "','" + columns[23] + "','" + columns[24] + "','" + columns[25] + "','" + columns[26] + "')";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
filas = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

El problema con hacerlo con el código arriba es que inserta datos en la primera tabla. Pero en la segunda ya no lo permite, pues el valor de `idPersona` lo lleva vacío y no sé cómo pasarle ese valor.

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que `idPersona` es una columna `identity`. De ser el caso, puedes usar [`scope_identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315.aspx) para recuperar el valor de `idPersona` del registro insertado en la tabla `personaFisica`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con código de cómo se puede usar esta técnica. Pero, por no conocer la estructura de tu tabla, voy a usar una versión simplificada de tus tablas. Pero la idea general del ejemplo es lo que cuenta.

Asumiendo las 2 tablas siguientes:

```sql
create table personaFisica (
  idPersona int identity not null primary key,
  nombre varchar(50) not null
);
go

create table diagnosticoFisico (
  idDiagnostico int identity not null primary key,
  idPersona int not null,
  constraint diagnosticoFisicoFk
  foreign key (idPersona)
  references personaFisica (idPersona)
);
go
```

Ejemplo de insert en las 2 tablas:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();

    int idPersona;

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "insert into personaFisica (nombre) values (@nombre); select cast(scope_identity() as int);",
        conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", "John Doe");
        idPersona = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "insert into diagnosticoFisico (idPersona) values (@idPersona)",
        conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPersona", idPersona);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Nota adicional**

Notarás que uso parámetros para incluir los valores en el insert, mas bien que concatenar los valores directamente en la cadena SQL. Te sugiero de adoptar esta práctica. Tiene muchas ventajas, y te protege de [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla/).

**Edición: Usando `OUTPUT` en vez de `scope_identity()`**

Una alternativa, que es un poco mejor que usar [`scope_identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315.aspx), es la de usar [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177564.aspx). Ambas opciones son muy similares y sirven el mismo propósito en esta situación. Pero en casos mas especiales envolviendo ciertos triggers, puede que `scope_identity()` no funcione correctamente.

Aquí tienes el código equivalente al anterior, pero usando `OUTPUT`:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();

    int idPersona;

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "insert into personaFisica (nombre) output inserted.idPersona values (@nombre)",
        conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", "John Doe");
        idPersona = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "insert into diagnosticoFisico (idPersona) values (@idPersona)",
        conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPersona", idPersona);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad por el consejo!
Y Gracias de nuevo, fue muy util tu ayuda.