# Validar formulario con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, session

yo ya tengo mi formulario y mis validaciones hechas, lo que enrealidad quiero es que cuando introduzca informacion en las cajas de texto **(input)** del formulario y cuando deje alguna caja de texto **(input)** vacias o con la valiadacion incorrecta, no se borre los campos que estan correctos al momento de que se actualiza el formulario para mostrar el mensaje de error

Veran tengo mi **formulario.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Nombre(s) del socio</label>
     <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese nombre...">
 </div>
 <?php     
   if(isset($_SESSION['error1'])){
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$_SESSION['error1']."</div>";
         }else{
          echo "";
         }
          unset($_SESSION['error1']);
    ?>
  <!-- /.form-group -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
      <input type="text" name="paterno" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese apellido...">
     </div>
      <?php     
       if(isset($_SESSION['error2'])){
         echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$_SESSION['error2']."</div>";
                }else{
                    echo "";
                }
                unset($_SESSION['error2']);
              ?>
              <!-- /.form-group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Apellido Materno</label>
                <input type="text" name="materno" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese apellido...">
              </div>
              <?php     
                if(isset($_SESSION['error3'])){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$_SESSION['error3']."</div>";
                }else{
                    echo "";
                }
                unset($_SESSION['error3']);
              ?>
              <!-- /.form-group -->
```

y tengo el archivo de mis **validaciones.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
    $nombre = $_POST["nom"];
    $paterno = $_POST["paterno"];
    $materno = $_POST["materno"];
$errores = array();

    if($nombre == ""){
        $errores[] = true;
        $_SESSION["error1"] = "¡Campo vacío! Ingrese el dato solicitado.";
    }
    if($paterno == ""){
        $errores[] = true;
        $_SESSION["error2"] = "¡Campo vacío! Ingrese el dato solicitado.";
    }
    if($materno == ""){
        $errores[] = true;
        $_SESSION["error3"] = "¡Campo vacío! Ingrese el dato solicitado.";
    }
   if(count($errores)>0){
        header("Location: form_add.php");
    }else{
    //aqui hago la consulta para agrgar los datos a la BD


       $_SESSION['exito']="¡Registro éxitoso!";
                header("Location: lista_socios.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cada uno de los `inputs` que tienes en tu formulario, deberás añadir el atributo `value` y darle el valor ingresado por el usuario.

```
<input value="<?=$nombre?>" type="text" name="materno" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese apellido...">
```

Para adaptarlo a tu código lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

En validaciones.php cuando compruebas que hay un error y debes de volver al formulario, debes de pasarle los valores que el usuario había introducido, puedes hacerlo por sesiones o por por `GET`.

**Ejemplo GET (El usuario vería los parámetros en la URL)**

```
if(count($errores)>0){
     header('Location: form_add.php?nombre='.$nombre.'&paterno='.$paterno);
}
```

**Ejemplo SESIONES (Ocultarlo a la vista del usuario)**

```
 if(count($errores)>0){
     $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre;
     $_SESSION['paterno'] = $paterno;
     header('Location: form_add.php');
 }
```

Ahora en formulario.php, debes de mostrar los valores que mandas en validaciones.php La funcionalidad de los siguientes códigos es comprobar si `$_SESSION[]` o `$_GET[]` tienen algo definido si es así pasarle el valor a una variable y sino iniciar esa variable en un valor vacío.

**Ejemplo con sesiones:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){ $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre']; }else{ $nombre = ''; } 
if(isset($_SESSION['paterno'])){ $paterno = $_SESSION['paterno']; }else{ $paterno = ''; }
```

**Ejemplo con GET:**

```
if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){ $nombre = $_GET['nombre']; }else{ $nombre = ''; } 
if(isset($_GET['paterno'])){ $paterno = $_GET['paterno']; }else{ $paterno = ''; }
```

Ambas dos son muy similares, esta es la parte común de ambos ejemplos, deberás seguir los ejemplos para cada uno de los `inputs`:

```
<input value="<?=$paterno?>" type="text" name="paterno" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese apellido...">
```

PD: Deberías de leer [cómo evitar una inyección sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla/10519#10519) y también [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233), te lo comento porque he visto el siguiente código y no haces uso de `real_escape_string`:

```
$nombre = $_POST["nom"];
$paterno = $_POST["paterno"];
$materno = $_POST["materno"];
```

Si realizas una consulta a la base de datos con alguna de las variables anteriores tal y como están tu código es vulnerable a inyecciones sql.

Comment: Disculpa y donde declaro la variable para que no me salga el error del que hace mencion.. Disculpe es que apenas me estoy familiarizando con php :(

Comment: Antes de responderte, ¿Cómo accedes al archivo validaciones? ¿Mandas allí el formulario o lo incluyes en el código de formulario.php?

Comment: lo incluyo en el formulario, con el  action=""

Comment: @Anthony He modificado mi respuesta, quizás ahora te aclare un poco más las ideas.

Comment: excelente, eres genial, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Anthony Me alegra de que te haya servido, si tienes cualquier duda de cómo funciona algún fragmento del código, puedes dejarla por aquí.

Comment: Disculpa ya por ultimo, como se le podria hacer para que no quede almacenada los datos en los inputs? porque ya termine de hacer el registro, ya refresco la pagina y cuando vuelvo a colocarme en el formulario, sigue pareciendo la informacion que introduje anteriormente..

Comment: Con `unset($_SESSION['nombre']);` deja de existir la sesión mencionada.

Comment: ese lo pongo dentro del input value="<?=$nombre?>" o dentro de esto; if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){ $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre']; }else{ $nombre = ''; }

Comment: @AntoTGa está muy bien la recomendación para evitar la inyección SQL, pero conviene usar [sentencias preparadas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127)

Comment: @Anthony ¿Cuando debes de vaciar la sesión? Cuando la hayas utilizado, por ello debes ponerlo después de usarla.

Comment: @Mariano Toda la razón, me lo guardo para futuras recomendaciones.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Mariano por su conocimiento he aprendido algo nuevo ... Un gran saludo

Comment: Igual a usted @AntoTGa por brindarme su conociemiento