# Insertar múltiple data usando jQuery y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Tengo el siguiente código:**
HTML formulario:

```
<form name="data" id="insert">
    <input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="telefono[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="apellido[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="direccion[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="btn_insert" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").submit( function () {    
        $.post(
               'insertar.php',
               $(this).serialize(),
               function(data){
                   $("#resultado").html(data)
               }
        );
        return false;   
    });   
});
```

**Archivo Insertar.php**

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
    $q="INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, telefono, apellido, direccion) VALUES ('".$_POST['nombre'][$i]."','".$_POST['telefono'][$i]."','".$_POST['apellido'][$i]."','".$_POST['direccion'][$i]."') "; 
    $result = $conexion->query($q);
}
if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Insertado exitosamente";
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error ". $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

El problema es que me genera que hubo una inserción exitosa pero no me inserta nada, ¿qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: los datos llegan a insertar.php?

Comment: entiendo que llegan ya que me generaría un error lo que no entiendo por que no los inserta es como si me enviase datos vacios, voy a revisar para estar seguro...

Comment: Si tienes un solo formulario, con un identificador, y tienes x campos, cada uno con sus nombres, por que en el archivo insertar.php recorres `count($id)` por que no simplemente envias el formulario, y en al ingresar, solo ingresas el valor del POST (del formulario) en la tabla?

Comment: ¿La tabla en la que se insertan los datos se llama `tabla` o es sólo un ejemplo que has puesto?

Comment: De donde sale $sql?. Haces insert con $q y luego usas $sql

Answer (score 1):

El código que compartes presenta varios problemas:

1. Es vulnerable a ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla): esto realmente no afecta a la funcionalidad de tu PHP, pero es un grave problema de seguridad que deberías solucionar cuanto antes. No deberías usar consultas dinámicas sino sentencias preparadas.
2. En algunos sitios haces referencia a la conexión como `$conexion` en otros como `$conn`: aunque esto no debería ser el problema porque `$conn` sólo se usa cuando ocurre un fallo y según indicas en la pregunta, el problema es que te dice que hubo una inserción exitosa pero realmente no inserta nada.
3. Estás ejecutando código SQL indefinido: por un lado estás ejecutando la inserción  y guardando el resultado en `$result` con:

   ```
   $result = $conexion->query($q)
   ```

   pero a la hora de mostrar el mensaje de error, no usas el `$result` sino que ejecutas una nueva consulta:

   ```
   if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE)
   ```

   y esa consulta es `$sql`, que no está definida en ningún sitio en el código de la pregunta y que podría ser cualquier cosa. Lo que sea esa consulta, el resultado es válido y por eso muestra el mensaje de insertado correctamente, pero realmente ese mensaje no se corresponde con el código de inserción.

Arregla esos problemas y comprueba si sigue ocurriendo el error.

Answer (score 0):

Doy por supuesto que los errores en los nombres de las variables se deben al hecho de que no posteas tu código real.

Dicho esto, prueba usando

```
$conn->exec ($sql);
```

Puesto que query es sólo un método de comodidad para sentencias de lectura.

Ojo con las inyecciones sql en ese código.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos Alvaro, amenadiel , voy a probar sus sugerencias

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hago es algo más o menos así

```
 $supp = $_POST["suppliers"];
 $query  = "INSERT INTO tabla (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ";
        $i = 0;
        $x = count($supp)-1;
        foreach ($supp as $value) {
            $query .= "('$user','$value','$id')";
            if($i<$x){
                $query .= ", ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

suponiendo que $_POST["suppliers"] proviene de una lista multiple.

La ventaja de usarlo así es que haces la insercción en una sola consulta a diferencia de como lo tienes que genera una consulta en cada iteración del ciclo, lo cual es más lento.

por cierto, `".$_POST['direccion'][$i]."`, esto lo puedes simplificar así: `{$_POST['direccion'][$i]}`
    De esta manera en vez de abrir y cerrar comillas y concatenar con punto solo lo encierras entre llaves {}