# ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos de una consulta PHP en una tabla HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

Saludos, tengo el siguiente inconveniente, resulta que estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos con diferentes campos, y estoy obteniendo los resultados de la siguiente manera.

```
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo "<table class= main-container>";
echo $fila ['COD_CONSULTA']. "";
echo $fila ['CED_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['NOM_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['APE_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['SEX_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['ALT_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['PESO_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['FECHA']. "";
echo $fila ['TIPO_CONSULTA']. "";
echo $fila ['SINTOMAS']. "";
echo $fila ['OBSERV']. "";
echo $fila ['HIS_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['MEDI_PAC']. "";
echo $fila ['OPERADO']. "";
echo $fila ['ALERGIAS']. "</table>";

echo "<br> ";
echo "<br> ";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

}
```

Pues bien, tengo una tabla creada en HTML y quiero que esos resultados se me muestren en la tabla para poder aplicarle un estilo de CSS y que se vea agradable ¿Alguien sabe como?

Esta es mi tabla.

```html
<div id="main-container">
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Codigo Consulta</th><th>Cedula</th><th>Nombres</th><th>Apellidos</th><th>Estatura</th><th>Peso</th><th>Tipo consulta</th><th>Sintomas</th><th>Observaciones</th><th>Medicamentos actuales</th><th>Alergias</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr>

</div>
```

**EDIT:** Este es el codigo de la pagina entera por si alguien lo quiere ver (Acá aun no tengo agregada la tabla, si alguien puede ayudarme con eso, pues tengo en primer lugar un recuadro de busqueda y al hacer la consulta recarga la pagina y muestra la consulta)

```html
<?php 

 function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda){
 include("conexiond.php");

 $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

  echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
  exit();
 }

 mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


 $consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

 $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

 while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 echo "<table class= main-container>";
 echo $fila ['COD_CONSULTA']. "";
 echo $fila ['CED_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['NOM_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['APE_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['SEX_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['ALT_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['PESO_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['FECHA']. "";
 echo $fila ['TIPO_CONSULTA']. "";
 echo $fila ['SINTOMAS']. "";
 echo $fila ['OBSERV']. "";
 echo $fila ['HIS_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['MEDI_PAC']. "";
 echo $fila ['OPERADO']. "";
 echo $fila ['ALERGIAS']. "</table>";

 echo "<br> ";
 echo "<br> ";
 }

 mysqli_close($conexion);

 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

  $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

  if($mibusqueda!=NULL){
   ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
  }else{
   echo ("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
    <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
     <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
     <div class='contenedor'>
     <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

     <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
    </div>
    </form>");
  }
 ?>

 
<!--</body>  // Esta seria la tabla que me debe aparecer al hacer la consulta, no se como agregarla.
</html>

<div id="main-container">
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Codigo Consulta</th><th>Cedula</th><th>Nombres</th><th>Apellidos</th><th>Estatura</th><th>Peso</th><th>Tipo consulta</th><th>Sintomas</th><th>Observaciones</th><th>Medicamentos actuales</th><th>Alergias</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr>

</div>
```

Comment: Este código presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad y no debería ser utilizado en un entorno de producción. Lee sobre [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/250) y [cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes hacer que la función `ejecuta_consulta` devuelva un arreglo (`array`) con los datos de los pacientes y después lo recorres mediante un bucle para ir imprimiendo cada elemento dentro de la columna (`td`) correspondiente.

```
<?php

    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {
        include("conexiond.php");

        $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo Consulta</th>
                        <th>Cedula</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Estatura</th>
                        <th>Peso</th>
                        <th>Tipo consulta</th>
                        <th>Sintomas</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                        <th>Medicamentos actuales</th>
                        <th>Alergias</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['COD_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['CED_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['NOM_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['APE_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SEX_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALT_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['PESO_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['FECHA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['TIPO_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SINTOMAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OBSERV'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['HIS_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['HIS_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['MEDI_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OPERADO'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALERGIAS'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
                <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Matia, me ha solucionado el problema, muchas gracias, solo una cosa ¿Como podría quitar el encabezado que se ve en el primer recuadro de busqueda? para que solo salga cuando realizo la busqueda.

http://imgur.com/a/DPf5N

Aqui te muestro a lo que me refiero

Comment: @PabloPernia Edite la respuesta, ahora no se debería ver el encabezado de la tabla

Comment: Muchas gracias Matias, ya me funciona perfecto, saludos, ya marque tu respuesta como la que soluciono.