# ¿Existe alguna función que evalúe una expresión matemática con varios operadores en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estado viendo ejemplos encontre este:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
       -> 2
```

pero yo ocupo que me de el resultado  de un string en su totalidad seria algo así `SELECT '2*2+3'`.

Comment: Bienvenido Jesus!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Para hacer cálculos matemáticos no se deben usar las comillas, quedaría de la siguiente manera: `SELECT 2 * 2 + 3;`

Answer (score 1):

El motor de SQL es capaz de evaluar expresiones matemáticas de forma nativa, por ejemplo: `SELECT (2+3)/2`, sin embargo, en tu caso, lo que intentas es evaluar una expresión que pudiera estar guardada en una cadena ya sea en variable o en una columna. Para resolverlo puedes aprovechar las [sentencias dinámicas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) de la siguiente manera:

```
set @formula = '(2+3)/2';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ''', @formula, ''' FORMULA,', @formula, ' RESULTADO');
PREPARE StmtStd FROM @sql;
EXECUTE StmtStd;
```

Salida:

```
╔═══╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ # ║ FORMULA ║ RESULTADO ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1 ║ (2+3)/2 ║ 2,5000    ║
╚═══╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

### Importante:

Las sentencias dinámicas son muy útiles pero si no tenemos control sobre las mismas, es un a puerta abierta a cualquier ataque de [inyección de sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla).