# Login con tipo de usuario (administrador/normal) usando c#

Tags: c#

Actualmente este es mi código pero no me abre el formulario para administrador u operaciones pero sí identifica de qué tipo es.

Entra al `if 1` o `2` pero no carga el siguiente formulario.

```
public void logear(string rut, string pass)
{
    try {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id_tipousuario from tb_usuarios_adm where run_usuario = '"+rut+"' AND password= '"+pass+"'", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count == 1){
            this.Hide();
            if(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "1")
            {
                new administrador.Principal_administrador(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()).Show();
                con.Close();
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "2")
            {
                new operaciones.principal_operaciones(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()).Show();
                con.Close();
            }
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception f) { }
}
```

Comment: Hola Sebastián, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tengo unas dudas y observaciones acerca del problema qué presentas. La primera es que por ningún motivo debes armas consultas concatenadas, tu código es suceptible a [SQL Injection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10519/16841), debes utilizar *Stored Procedures* o consultas parametrizadas. La segunda, al decir que no te abre el formulario te refieres a que no te abre el `Principal_administrador` o el `principal_operaciones`?

Comment: Una búsqueda indica que una forma de hacerlo es creando la instancia del formulario, por ejemplo: `var principal_administrador = new Principal_administrador(); principal_administrador.Show();`.

Comment: claro necesito pasarle la variable 1 del select (rut/dni) al siguiente formulario pero no abre ninguno de los 2 independientemente que el usuario sea administrador o operaciones. entra al if identificando uno de los 2 pero no pasa al siguiente formulario.

Comment: ¿Tus formularios los declaras recibiendo el parámetro que requieres? Por ejemplo, `public Principal_administrador(string algunaCadena){ InitializeComponent(); //el resto de tu código }`

Comment: public principal_operaciones(string rut){
            InitializeComponent();
            lblrut.Text = rut;
        }

Comment: Otra cosa es que asegures que llevas algo en `dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()` ;)

Comment: public Principal_administrador(string rut)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblrut.Text = rut;

Comment: exactamente ese era el error, no llevaba nada al siguiente formulario ni tampoco sacaba desde la base de datos el rut ya que solo extraia el id_tipousuario.

Comment: gracias =) =) =)

Answer (score 2):

Saludos! Intenta creando primero una instancia del formulario. Prueba lo siguiente dentro del `if`:

```
if(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "1")
{
    administrador.Principal_administrador Admin = new administrador.Principal_administrador(rut);
    Admin.Show();
    con.Close();
}
else if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "2")
{
    operaciones.principal_operaciones Operation = new operaciones.principal_operaciones(rut);
    Operation.Show();
    con.Close();
}
```

Cambie el `dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()` por `rut` porque según tu comentario, es lo que recibe el formulario, en vez del número que identifica al tipo de usuario (1 o 2 dependiendo de lo que se retorna en el `id_tipousuario`. Puedes cambiarlo para que se ajuste a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasaba lo mismo que a ti, no entra a tu formulario porque desborda el indice, solo cambia dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1", las columnas y filas en cero, igual en el otro if, y listo!