# Como mostrar los pedidos por cliente desde mysql

Tags: php, html, html-tabla

Estoy formulando de nuevo la pregunta, con más información y datos.
Para que me puedan entender algo mejor:

"Edito de nuevo la pregunta.

Quiero mostrar, los pedidos a cada cliente:
Leyendo desde el mysql.

El historial lo tengo compuesto de la siguiente manera:

**Validación del cargo de usuario**

```html
<?php
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['cargo']) || $_SESSION['cargo'] != 2){
    header('index.php');
    $idusuario = $_SESSION['id']
  }
?>
```

**Estructura de la tabla:**

```html
      <?php
        require('conexion.php');
       
        $query="SELECT *  FROM historial WHERE id = '$idusuario' ORDER BY fecha DESC;";

        $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
        
      ?>      
      <table id="orders" cellspacing="0" class="orders"> 
        <thead>
          <tr class="centro">
            <th >Order</th>
            <th >Fecha</th>
            <th >Cliente</th>>
            <th >Referencia</th>
            <th >Familia</th>
            <th >Ojo Derecho</th>
            <th >Ojo Izquierdo</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>       
            <?php 
            while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['ordern'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['fecha'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['cliente'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['referencia'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['familia'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['od'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $row['oi'];?>
                </td> 
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Tal cuál está:
Me saca error en esta linea:

```html
while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
```

"Call to a member function fetch_assoc()"

He probado varias cosas según las respuestas, pero me saca error.
No consigo que me llegue a mostrar los del cliente."

Comment: He aportado [una respuesta bastante documentada en tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114247/29967)  con miras a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Seguramente tienes un error en la consulta por lo que **$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);** te está devolviendo **false** en lugar de un objeto **mysqli_result**

Answer (score 1):

Hola colega intenta con esto

```
 $query="SELECT *  FROM historial WHERE id = '$idusuario' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
  $mysqli->query($query);
  $resultado= $mysqli->use_result();

  ?>      
  <table id="orders" cellspacing="0" class="orders"> 
    <thead>
      <tr class="centro">
        <th >Order</th>
        <th >Fecha</th>
        <th >Cliente</th>>
        <th >Referencia</th>
        <th >Familia</th>
        <th >Ojo Derecho</th>
        <th >Ojo Izquierdo</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>       
        <?php 
        while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['ordern'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['fecha'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['cliente'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['referencia'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['familia'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['od'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['oi'];?>
            </td> 
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```