# Concatenar variable php con consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql

No me deja concatenar la siguiente consulta me tira error

```html
$consulta_url="select url from urlspeliculas where idioma='$idiomas[$f][$g]'";
```

los ultimos  corchete en $idiomas[$f][$g] me lo toma como texto, alguna solucion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución rápida, mas no la óptima sería modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
$idioma = $idiomas[$f][$g];
$consulta_url = "select url from urlspeliculas where idioma = '$idioma'";
```

De este modo capturarías el valor del índice de arreglo dentro de la variable $idioma y luego pasarías esta como una cadena dentro de $consulta_url.

De persistir el error, sería interesante saber el contenido del mismo.

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: buena solucion gracias

Comment: `select url from urlspeliculas where idioma = '$idioma'` es una consulta vulnerable a la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/29967). Es un tipo de ataque que puede llegar a alcanzar un nivel de gravedad que [va más allá de la base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967).

Comment: En efecto la consulta en cuestión sería vulnerable a inyección sql. La manera correcta de ejecutarla y con menos riezgos actualmente, sería configurar una conexión PDO y asignar la variable idioma dentro de un bindValue. Pero como dice la respuesta esta es la solución rápida.

Comment: @A.Cedano GRACIAS no tenia conocimiento sobre este tema ya que soy nuevo en PHP, me has ayudado a aprender