# Error en PHP Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de obtener un id desde una base de datos pero me ha surgido el siguiente error:
**Array to string conversion**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'funciones.php';
$pwd=md5('pwd');
$respuesta = funciones::login('user', $pwd);
if ($respuesta) 
{
echo "$respuesta[0];";
}
else
{
echo "Ninguna coincidencia con la busqueda...";
}
?>
```

Y el codigo de la función 'login' es:

```
    public static function login($user, $pwd)
    {
        $consultar = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '$user' AND pwd = '$pwd'";
        $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
        $resultado->execute();
        $tabla = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $tabla;
    }
```

**NOTA: La configuración de la base de datos si esta bien, por que si obtiene un resultado, el error esta en la linea: echo "$respuesta[0];";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que un problema puede ser que estas concatenando mal sería algo como esto

```
$consultar = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '".$user."' AND pwd = '".$pwd."'";
```

Es decir antes y despues de las variables va por ejemplo:  '".$user."'

Comment: pues fíjate que no, por que he podido imprimir los resultados así:
echo json_encode($respuesta);

Comment: Pero lo que quiero hacer es guardar el dato que obtengo en una variable y no se como

Comment: puedes poner lo que imprime echo json_encode($respuesta);? o al menos un ejemplo?

Comment: [{"id":"1","user":"user","pwd":"9003d1df22eb4d3820015070385194c8","apodo":"JoDeR"}]

Comment: intenta con esto y me dices    echo $respuesta["id"];

Comment: Apareció esto:
Notice: Undefined index: id

Comment: echo $respuesta->id; me dices

Comment: Ahora esto: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: pon esto y me dices que muestra, var_dump($respuesta)

Comment: Apareció lo siguiente: array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user"]=> string(4) "user" ["pwd"]=> string(32) "9003d1df22eb4d3820015070385194c8" ["apodo"]=> string(5) "JoDeR" } }

Comment: prueba esto echo $respuesta[0]["id"]

Comment: Eso me ha impreso el dato que quería, muchas gracias enserio, llevaba investigando un buen rato y no hallaba solución, gracias enserio

Answer (score 1):

Dado que la respuesta dada no ha indicado una grave vulnerabilidad en el código, me permito aportar una respuesta que resolvería no solamente el actual error, sino que blindaría el código contra inyección de código malicioso.

Se trataría de usar consultas preparadas del siguiente modo:

```
   public static function login($user, $pwd)
    {
        $consultar = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = ? AND pwd = ?";
        $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
        $arrParams=array($user,$pwd);
        $resultado->execute($arrParams);
        $tabla = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $tabla;
    }
```

Como se puede ver, blindar el código contra la Inyección SQL es muy fácil en PDO:

1. Escribes la instrucción SQL cambiando las variables por marcadores de posición (`?`). También se podrían usar marcadores de nombre. Este es el núcleo de la Inyección, ya que un usuario mal intencionado podría modificar esos valores cambiándolos por código malicioso inyectable. Al pasarlos en la consulta y ejecutarla, podrías estar ejecutando código manipulado que podría ser muy muy dañino. Por eso no deberías **nunca** mandar a ejecutar consultas de este tipo: <s>`SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = '$user' AND pwd = '$pwd'`</s>
2. Creas un array (`$arrParams`) con los valores que provienen desde fuentes externas.
3. Pasas ese array con los valores a través del método `execute`.

Con esos tres sencillos pasos, estás blindando tu código contra el ataque de intrusos.

Para más detalles puedes consultar estas preguntas y sus respuestas:

- [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)
- [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/29967)
- [¿La Inyección SQL actúa sólo a nivel de la base de datos o el riesgo es aún mayor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967)

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gran explicación.