# Buscador de registros mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de implementar un buscador de palabra en una tabla mysql

Tengo un buscador de número que, aun siendo muy sencillo, funciona a la perfección:

```html
<?php if ($row['albaran'] == $_POST['buscar']): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Esto muestra el registro si albarán es exactamente igual al número que introduzco en el formulario de buscar.

Pero me gustaría que buscase una coincidencia, que no sea exácta. Por ejemplo: Buscar "Pedro" en un registro que sea "Pedro Romero Tomas"

He probado algo así

```html
$buscarcliente = $_POST['buscarcliente'];

sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE cliente LIKE "%$buscarcliente%"';
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿qué problema te da el SQL? ¿has probado a poner la SQL en mysql directamente por ejemplo con phpmyadmin? en cualquier caso, deberías revisar el tema de SQL Injection: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Comment: No queda claro cual es el problema, por otro lado tampoco entiendo por qué necesitas un if para comparar el número, sería mucho más eficiente hacer el filtrado directamente con SQL.

Comment: Necesito saber si el código sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE cliente LIKE "%$buscarcliente%"'; está bien formulado para buscar una palabra en una frase en mysql

Comment: **Lo menos** que tendrás en tu código es un *error de sintaxis*. Cuando tengas que usar en la instrucción SQL comillas simples dentro (como es el caso aquí), debes empezar tu variable por comillas dobles, no al revés. O sea: `$sql="SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE cliente LIKE '%$buscarcliente%'";`. **Lo más grave**, cuando el código funcione, es que te cuelen una [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) que destruya tus datos o que [permita a un hacker tomar el control de tu sistema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967). Blinda tu código usando consultas preparadas.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección gracias, voy a investigar para hacer consultas preparadas, gracias por la info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas `LIKE`, el comodín `%` es el indicado para hacer coincidir cualquier cadena de cero o más caracteres, tal y como indica la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).

El problema de tu código radica en la forma en que estás usando las comillas dobles `"` y las comillas simples `'`. El uso de `LIKE` requiere que el dato a buscar y el comodín vayan rodeados de comillas simples `'`, por lo tanto, en este caso conviene que la declaración de tu variable vaya rodeada de comillas dobles.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE cliente LIKE '%$buscarcliente%'";
```

---

### Problema de seguridad en tu código

Quiero indicar que en tu código hay algo mucho más grave: el mismo es vulnerable a la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967). A través de ella un [usuario mal intencionado podría destruir tus datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967), o podría incluso tomar el control de tu sistema. Es importante que blindes tu código usando consultas preparadas.