# ERROR insertar datos JDBC MYSQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Llevo todo el día de ayer intentando insertar los datos que recibo por el scanner a la base de datos y me da error, no encuentro la solución por ningún lado.

Me sale este mensaje de error:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error  in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server  version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at
>   line 1 at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:899) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:737) at
>   inventario.SwitchInt.RegistrarProducto(SwitchInt.java:59) at
>   inventario.Inventario.main(Inventario.java:31)

He cambiado la sintaxis mas de 20 veces literalmente, pero no lo consigo.
En clase estamos acostumbrado hacerlo con postgre y es diferente, he buscado la sintaxis de mysql y me ponían que era la que tengo puesta, pero no me va, os dejo abajo el código.

Clase Conexion

```
public class Conexion {

Connection conexion = null;
Statement comando = null;
ResultSet registro;

public Connection MySQLConnect() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventario";
        String usuario = "root";
        String pass = "";
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, usuario, pass);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        conexion = null;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        conexion = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        conexion = null;
    } finally {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion establecida correctamente.");
        return conexion;
    }
}

PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String insert_into_usuarioNombreApellidosEdadCor) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Aquí tengo el error, en esta clase.

```
public class SwitchInt {

**Conexion db = new Conexion();
Connection cn = db.MySQLConnect();**


static String nombre;
static double precio;
static int opcion, stock, codigo;
Producto p;
Vector<Producto> productos = new Vector<Producto>();

public void Intro() {
    System.out.print("\nElija un número:\n 1. Registrar producto\n 2. Vender producto\n 3. Buscar producto\n 4. Calcular precio medio\n 5. Salir \n\n ");
}

public void RegistrarProducto() throws SQLException {
    System.out.print("\n Ingrese un código del producto: \n");
    codigo = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    nombre = entrada.next();
    System.out.print("Precio: ");
    precio = entrada.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Stock: ");
    stock = entrada.nextInt();
    p = busqueda(codigo, productos);

    if (p == null) {
        productos.addElement(new Producto(codigo, nombre, precio, stock));

        **String sql = "INSERT INTO productos (ID, Nombre, Precio, Stock) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pst;
        pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, codigo);
        pst.setString(2, nombre);
        pst.setDouble(3, precio);
        pst.setInt(4, stock);
        pst.execute(sql);**

        System.out.print("Producto agregado\n");
    } else {
        System.out.print("ya existe este producto");
    }
}
```

Agradezco una pequeña ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Has probado la consulta SQL directamente contra la base de datos? Te devuelve el mismo error?

Comment: Si, directamente en la base de datos si me coge la consulta, pero claro, nunca he probado el VALUES(?,?,?,?), no se si tengo algún error de código o algo

Comment: Has probado a:
`INSERT INTO productos (ID, Nombre, Precio, Stock) VALUES(" + String.valueOf(codigo) + "," + nombre + ", " + String.valueOf(precio) + "," + String.valueOf(stock) + ")"`

Comment: @rencinas  Me da este error:    
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).


Busqué en google y me ponía que cambiara de controlador jdbc, que podría ser eso, lo he cambiado y sigue igual.

Comment: @rencinas no recomiendes eso. El uso de `?` es para evitar la Inyección de código, lo cual ocurre precisamente si se pasa la consulta como indicas. Es una mala práctica y muy peligroso ejecutar consultas concatenando valores externos.

Comment: Manuee, **deja el código tal y como está, con los `?`**, ya que tu error está aquí: `pst.execute(sql);`, debes cambiarlo por esto : **`pst.executeUpdate();`**

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando se usan consultas preparadas, que es lo correcto en este caso<sup>1</sup>, el método que ejecuta la sentencia es  [**`executeUpdate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--), no <s>`execute`</s>.

> #### `executeUpdate`
>
> Ejecuta la instrucción SQL en este objeto `PreparedStatement`, que
>   debe ser una declaración de SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML), como
>   `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`; o una declaración SQL que no devuelve
>   nada, como una instrucción DDL.

Además, la instrucción SQL ya fue pasada aquí: `pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);`, luego sólo queda ejecutar, no hay que pasar de nuevo la variable `sql` en  `executeUpdate`.

Si escribes tu código así, debería funcionar:

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO productos (ID, Nombre, Precio, Stock) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pst;
    pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setInt(1, codigo);
    pst.setString(2, nombre);
    pst.setDouble(3, precio);
    pst.setInt(4, stock);
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1</sup> Cuando en una consulta intervienen datos externos hay que aplicar siempre el principio de **consultas preparadas**, de lo contrario nuestro código sería vulnerable a un grave riesgo de seguridad conocido como **Inyección SQL**, a través del cual un usuario mal intencionado podría tomar el control **no solamente de nuestra base de datos, [sino de todo el sistema operativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967)**.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! me funciono a la perfección sin ningún error, de verdad muchas gracias !

Comment: @Manuee, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.