# Error de Sintaxis PHP/MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, date, update

¿Que ocurre? Creo que esta bien construida, pero obviamente algo esta fallando.

Nombre de la Tabla: `citas`

Nombre de los Campos: `idcita, horacita, diacita, asuntocita`

> Error de Consulta 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'diacita='2018-11-14' asuntocita='df' WHERE idcita
>   = 22' at line 1

```
$fechaBD = $_POST['anio']."-".$_POST['mes']."-".$_POST['dia'];
$horaBD = $_POST['hora'].":".$_POST['min'];

    $modificarQuery = "UPDATE citas SET horacita='".$horaBD."' diacita='".$fechaBD."' asuntocita='".$_POST['asuntoCita']."' WHERE idcita = ".$idCita;

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $modificarQuery);

    if(!$result){
                  die("Error de Consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion)." ".mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Comment: Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967). Se trata de un agujero de seguridad [a través del cual un usuario mal intencionado podría tomar el control no solamente de tu base de datos, sino de todo el sistema operativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967). Convendría que uses consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.

Answer (score 2):

Sí, está bien formada, pero te faltan comas entre cada uno de los parámetros que le pasas a la consulta. La formación de update es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Añadiéndole las comas, debería funcionarte, salvo que tengas alguna columna que no corresponda a la tabla.

Comment: Documentación extraía de [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: Completamente cierto... no se como se me ha podido pasar en el rato que llevo dándole vueltas. Gracias.