# Problema en variable conexion undefined

Tags: php, postgresql

El código es este:

archivo conn-->Conexión a la base de datos:

```
<?php

class conn
{

    //Atributos de la base de datos
    private $dbname;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $port;

    //Métodos
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbname = "scrum";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->user = "postgres";
        $this->pass = "1234";
        $this->port = "5432";
        try{
        $conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->host.
                            ";port=".$this->port.
                            ";dbname=".$this->dbname.
                            ";user=".$this->user.
                            ";password=".$this->pass);
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Tienes el siguiente error:", $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function consultaSimple($sql)
    {
        $conexion->query($sql);
    }

    public function consultaCompleja($sql)
    {
        $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $consulta;
    }

}
```

Error al tratar de incluirlo en el archivo **`inicio.php`** que es una vista del sistema en la cual hago un listado. Lo cual me dice que la variable conexión se encuentra vacía; sin embargo, se genera la conexión.

Código de controlador:

```
<?php


include_once("clases/source.php");

class controlador
{
    //Atributos
    private $usuario;

    //Métodos

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usuario = new source();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $resultado = $this->usuario->listar();
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function crear($nombre, $apellido, $username, $pass, $correo)
    {
        $this->usuario->set("nombre",$nombre);
        $this->usuario->set("apellido",$apellido);
        $this->usuario->set("username",$username);
        $this->usuario->set("pass",$pass);
        $this->usuario->set("correo",$correo);

        $resultado = $this->usuario->crear();
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function eliminar($id)
    {
        $this->usuario->set("id",$id);
        $this->usuario->eliminar();
    }

    public function ver($id)
    {
        $this->usuario->set("id",$id);
        $this->usuario->ver();
    }

    public function editar($id)
    {
        $this->usuario->set("id",$id);
        $this->usuario->ver();
        $this->usuario->editar();
    }
}
```

?>

Código de source y funciones CRUD:

```
<?php

//Incluimos la clase de conexión
include_once('conn.php');

class source
{
    //Atributos principales
    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    private $apellido;
    private $username;
    private $pass;
    private $correo;

    private $conexion;

    //Métodos CRUD

    //constructor de la classe conexión
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conexion = new conn();
    }

    //Fijamos o establecemos el valor del atributo que venga a partir del formulario
    public function set($atributo, $contenido)
    {
        $this->atributo = $contenido;
    }

    //Obtenemos el atributo o dato a través del formulario
    public function get($atributo)
    {
        return $this->atributo;
    }

    public function listar()
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuario";
        $resultado = $this->conexion->consultaCompleja($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function crear()
    {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username = '{$this->username} or correo = '{$this->correo}' ";
        $resultado = $this->conexion->consultaCompleja($sql2);
        $num = fetchColumn($resultado);

        if (num != 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellido, username, correo, password) 
            VALUES ('{$this->nombre}','{$this->apellido}','{$this->username}','{$this->pass}','{$this->correo}')";

            $this->conexion->consultaSimple($sql);
            return true;
        }

    }

    public function eliminar()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE idusuario = '{$this->id}' ";
        $this->conexion->consultaSimple($sql);
    }

    public function ver()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE idusuario = '{$this->id}' ";
        $resultado = $this->conexion->consultaCompleja($sql);
        $row = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($resultado);

        //Set interno

        $this->id = $row['idusuario'];
        $this->nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $this->apellido = $row['apellido'];
        $this->username = $row['username'];
        $this->pass = $row['password'];
        $this->correo = $row['correo'];
    }

    public function editar()
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre = '{$this->nombre}', apellido = '{$this->apellido}', password = '{$this->pass}' 
        WHERE idusuario = '{$this->id}'";

        $this->conexion->consultaSimple($sql);

    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Muestra cómo lo estás incluyendo y usando la clase. ¿Seguro que escribiste la ruta de archivo correcta?

Comment: Osea es un CRUD en PHP orientado a objetos, en la vista llamo a un controlador y el controlador es el que llama a la conexión. Adjunto código del controlador.

Comment: A la clase le falta el miembro conexión al principio: `private $conexion;`.  Y debes asignarlo en el constructor: `$this->conexion = new PDO(...)` y en los otros métodos usarlo así: `$this->conexion->query($sql);` como lo tienes ahora la `$conexion` sólo estaría disponible en el constructor, pero no como un miembro de la clase para usarla en los otros métodos de la misma.

Comment: Voy a probarlo como lo dices, muchísimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tienes la clase, la conexión sólo queda disponible en el constructor. Para poder usarla en los otros métodos debes crear un miembro de la clase al que asignarle la conexión.

Por ejemplo:

```
class conn
{

    //Atributos de la base de datos
    private $dbname;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $port;
    private $conexion;

    //Métodos
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbname = "scrum";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->user = "postgres";
        $this->pass = "1234";
        $this->port = "5432";
        try{
        $this->conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->host.
                            ";port=".$this->port.
                            ";dbname=".$this->dbname.
                            ";user=".$this->user.
                            ";password=".$this->pass);
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Tienes el siguiente error:", $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function consultaSimple($sql)
    {
        $this->conexion->query($sql);
    }

    public function consultaCompleja($sql)
    {
        $consulta = $this->conexion->query($sql);
        return $consulta;
    }

}
```

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> La forma en que estás pasando tus consultas es altamente vulnerable a
>   ataques de [inyección
>   SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967). Se trata de un
>   agujero de seguridad [a través del cual un usuario mal intencionado
>   podría tomar el control no solamente de tu base de datos, sino de todo
>   el sistema operativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967).
>   Convendría que uses consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.