# Formulario con checkbox y mSql

Tags: php, formularios, checkbox, msql

**Resumen**

Necesito mandar datos por medio de un checkbox(Seleccion multiple) a mi base de datos Msql.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="arreglo[]"   value="3"/>3
<input type="checkbox" name="arreglo[]"   value="2"/>2
<input type="checkbox" name="arreglo[]"   value="1"/>1
```

**PHP**

```
$arreglo= $_POST['arreglo'];

foreach ($arreglo as $llave => $valor) {
$ficha2="INSERT INTO usuario (nombres, apellidos,email,medioComunicacion,
tipoOrganizacion, cargo, tipoInfo, interes,
 formPreferido) VALUES ('NOMBRE','APPELLIDO','EMAIL','MEDIOCOMUNI','$valor','cargo','tipoInfo','interes','formPreferido')";

$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$ficha2);
```

**PROBLEMA**

cuando ejecuto el codigo, no tengo errores, pero en la base de datos se registran registros no deseados,es decir; en el checkbox se selecciono 2 opciones, lo que quiero es que en la base de datos se Registre

|Otras Columnas  ||Arreglo|

|otros registros || 1,2   |

**Pero en realidad se registro**

|Otras Columnas  ||Arreglo|

|otros registros || 1     |

|otros registros || 2     |

Como puedo solucionar mi problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

la solucion es bastante sencilla, solo toca crear una variable que me genere la union del arreglo.

y eso se hace asi:

```
if (is_array($_POST['arreglo'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_pat = count($_POST['arreglo']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['arreglo'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($current != $num_pat-1)
            $selected .= $value.', ';
        else
            $selected .= $value.'';

        $current++;

    }
}

else{
    $selected = '';

}
```

ese selected lo ponemos en la Query ya.

Comment: No hace falta toooodo eso. Si en `$_POST['arreglo']` hay un array y quieres esos valores separados por coma, puedes lograrlo de una forma muy simple usando **[`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)**. Por ejemplo: **`$selected=implode(",",$_POST['arreglo']);`** ¿Y ya? Sí, y ya, con una sola línea, problema resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Si en `$_POST['arreglo']` hay un array y quieres esos valores separados por coma, puedes lograrlo de una forma muy simple usando **[`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)** el cual:

> Une elementos de un array en un string

#### Código de ejemplo

```
if (is_array($_POST['arreglo'])) {
    $valor=implode(",",$_POST['arreglo']); # Con una sola línea, resuelto ...
    $ficha2="INSERT INTO usuario (nombres, apellidos,email,medioComunicacion,
tipoOrganizacion, cargo, tipoInfo, interes,
 formPreferido) VALUES ('NOMBRE','APPELLIDO','EMAIL','MEDIOCOMUNI','$valor','cargo','tipoInfo','interes','formPreferido')";
    $result= mysqli_query($conexion,$ficha2);
}
```

#### Advertencia sobre la seguridad

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, mediante la cual un usuario mal intencionado podría tomar el control de tu servidor, modificar, eliminar o alterar datos en la base de datos, obtener accesos bloqueados, etc, es decir, [causar verdaderos estragos en tu entorno](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967). Considera corregir ese agujero de seguridad usando consultas preparadas.

Comment: muchas gracias!