# ¿COMO CARGAR DATOS SELECCIONADO EN UNA TABLA?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Esta es la función que agrega una nueva fila y la de mas abajo carga el select con los datos de la bbdd.

LA PRIMERA FILA SI CARGA EL DATO DE LA PATENTE SELECCIONADA. PERO AL AGREGAR OTRA FILA Y SELECCIONAR LA PATENTE NO ME CARGA EL KILOMETRAJE ANTERIOR.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AgregarFila").click(function(){
        var TablaKilometraje = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
        $("#tablaprueba").append("<tr>"+TablaKilometraje.rows[0].innerHTML+"</tr>");//1
        $('.borrar').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();//2

        });

    });
    
});  

</script>


       <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
           const select = document.getElementById('id_tracto');
           function CargarPatente() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Datos_Tracto_Kilometraje.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                const patente=(response)
                const options= document.createElement("option");
                  patente.forEach(departamento => {
                  const option = new Option(departamento.patentes , departamento.idtracto)
                  select.append(option)

                })
            }
        })
    }
    CargarPatente() 

    })
</script>
```

Aquí está la función donde se agregan las filas al momento de presionar el botón

```
  <script>
        function agregarFila(){

        document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<tr><td class="col-sm-3"><select class="form-select" id="id_tracto"><option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option></select></td><td class="col-sm-3"><input type="" class="form-control" id="kmactual" readonly></input></td><td class="col-sm-3"><input type="" class="form-control" ></input></td><td class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">ELIMINAR</button></td></tr>';

        }

  </script>
```

Esta es la tabla dinámica que se muestra en el html

```
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><select class="form-select" id="id_tracto" name="id_tracto[]"><option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option></select></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="kilometraje_actual"  name="kilometraje_actual[]" value="" readonly/></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><input type="" class="form-control" id="kilometraje_actual" name="kmactual" ></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger borrar" id="borrar" >ELIMINAR</button></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
```

#Esta funcion lo que hace es enviar los datos a la tabla según el select seleccionado.

```
            <script>
             $('#id_tracto').on('change', function() { 
              var valor= $(this).val();
              $.ajax({   
              data : { valor : valor },
              url : 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Cargar_Valor_Kilometraje.php',   
              dataType : 'json',
              type:  'POST',
              success : function(json) {
              $("#kilometraje_actual").val(json.kilometraje_actual);

              },
              error : function(xhr, status) {
              alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
              }
              });
            
              });

              </script>
```

#necesito de su ayuda estimado porque estoy atrapado en estas lineas de codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134818/discussion-on-question-by-keane1991-el-evento-solo-me-toma-la-primera-fila-de-la).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como hacer para que un dato se guarda en su fila correspondiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/521284/como-hacer-para-que-un-dato-se-guarda-en-su-fila-correspondiente)

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una condicion antes de agregar un option

```
const totalFilas= $('#myTable > tbody > tr').length;
if(constFilas > 0)
{
//aqui iria la lógica de tu codigo
}
```

Comment: agregue tu condición aun no me salen los datos en el select no pasa el evento. La función CargarPatente() no pasa a la tabla :( aun no se como solucionarlo

Comment: @A. Cedano ahora se pudo cargar los datos en el select. Pero no me carga el km anterior en la segunda fila