# ¿Como hacer para que un dato se guarda en su fila correspondiente?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Este script lo que hace es evaluar un dato de la bbdd y lo retorna a un input. El problema es que lo estoy ocupado en una tabla dinámica y al momento de ir agrando fila se va modificando solo la primera fila. no se van agregando según la fila correspondiente. Por ejemplo en la primera linea selecciono una patente xxxx00 y 100 km al agregar la segunda fila selecciono otra patente y su km es de 200km pero no se guarda en la misma fila y pasa la primera. Dado que la primera tiene 100km lo cambia a 200km. Cómo puedo solucionar ese problema.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#id_tracto', function(event) {
        var valor= $(this).val();

        console.log(valor);

        $.ajax({   
              data : { valor : valor },
              url : 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Cargar_Valor_Kilometraje.php',   
              dataType : 'json',
              type:  'POST',
              success : function(json) {
                $("#kilometraje_actual").val(json.kilometraje_actual);           
              },            
              error : function(xhr, status) {
                  alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
                  }
              });
          
        });

</script>
```

#Este script me ayuda agregar una nueva fila. Cada vez que presiono un botón se va cargado una nueva fila

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AgregarFila").click(function(){
        var TablaKilometraje = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
        $("#tablaprueba").append("<tr>"+TablaKilometraje.rows[0].innerHTML+"</tr>");//1
        $('.borrar').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();//2

        });

    });
    
});  

</script>
```

#Este script es el que llena el select

```
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
           const select = document.getElementById('id_tracto');
           function CargarPatente() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Datos_Tracto_Kilometraje.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                const patente=(response)
                const options= document.createElement("option");
                  patente.forEach(departamento => {
                  const option = new Option(departamento.patentes , departamento.idtracto)
                  select.append(option)

                })
            }
        })
    }
    CargarPatente() 

    })
</script>
```

#aqui estamos en el html

```
  <tbody id="tablaprueba">
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><select class="form-select" id="id_tracto" name="id_tracto[]"><option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option></select></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="kilometraje_actual[]" id="kilometraje_actual" value="" readonly/></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><input type="" class="form-control" id="kmactual" name="kmactual" ></td>
      <td class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger borrar" id="borrar" >ELIMINAR</button></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: @Marcos gracias por comentar. Para identificar tendría que ser en el tr de la tabla! y si fuera así como lo podría hacer. La lógica estoy un poco confundido.

Comment: Hola @keane1991, para hacerte entender mejor, considera añadir más contexto, por ejemplo, la estructura en el html y a ser posible el código php. Lo único que vemos aquí es que tras la respuesta escribes un valor en algo con id kilometraje_actual.

Comment: @Marcos te quiero agradecer por tu tiempo. De verdad me falta aun por seguir aprendiendo un poco más. Pero lo que tu me enviaste quedo muy bien. Estoy muy agradecido y que Dios te bendiga.

Comment: @keane1991, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuyo que el problema es que tienes varios elementos con la id kilometraje_actual. Recuerda que las ids no pueden repetirse. Al seleccionar por id, te está encontrando el primer elemento (en este caso en la 1º fila). Añade más contexto y podremos ayudarte mejor.

**EDITO para futuros lectores**: La respuesta de Marcos es mucho más completa y llegó antes de que yo terminase de elaborar la mía, debería ser marcada como la aceptada. Considera darle votos positivos.

#### Consejos adicionales relacionados

Esto es una mera opinión, pero creo que ya en 2022 es hora de dejar jQuery de lado. Recuerda que casi todo lo que aporta jQuery ya está integrado en JavaScript de forma nativa desde hace una buena cantidad de años y hoy día tiene soporte completo [(casi del 98%)](https://caniuse.com/queryselector). Por ejemplo [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para selección de elementos con sintaxis de selectores de CSS y [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) en lugar de $.ajax.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo estimado @Alex VJ. hay cosas que se pueden hacer mucho mejor y de a poco me he ido integrando nuevamente a la programación  :) bendiciones

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema se debe a que estas usando siempre los mismos `id` y por eso siempre se escribe el valor en el mismo campo.

Deberías usar `class` y [delegación de eventos](https://osmancea.medium.com/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686).

#### Ejemplo:

Detectar el cambio en los `select`

```
$("#tablaprueba").on('change', 'select.id_tracto', function() {
  var $select = $(this), // Obtenemos el select modificado
    $tr = $select.closest('tr'), // Buscamos el tr del select
    valor = $select.val();
    
  console.log(valor);

  $.ajax({
    data: {valor: valor},
    url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Cargar_Valor_Kilometraje.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json) {
      // Buscamos en los hijos del tr
      $tr.find("input.kilometraje_actual").val(json.kilometraje_actual);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
    }
  });
});
```

En la primer fila sacamos los `id` y utilizamos `class`

```html
    <tbody id="tablaprueba">
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-select id_tracto" name="id_tracto[]">
            <option value="">SELECCIONAR PATENTE</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control kilometraje_actual" name="kilometraje_actual[]" value="" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="" class="form-control kmactual" name="kmactual[]">
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger borrar">ELIMINAR</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Bonus!** Borrar fila

```
$("#AgregarFila").click(function() {
  var TablaKilometraje = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
  $("#tablaprueba").append("<tr>" + TablaKilometraje.rows[0].innerHTML + "</tr>");
});

$("#tablaprueba").on('click', 'button.borrar', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

---

#### Actualización

Para solucionar el problema con el `select` solo tenes que cambiar el selector.

Ejemplo:

```
// Actualizamos el selector
const select = document.querySelector('select.id_tracto');

function CargarPatente() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Cargar_Datos_Kilometraje/Datos_Tracto_Kilometraje.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      const patente = (response)
      const options = document.createElement("option");
      patente.forEach(departamento => {
        const option = new Option(departamento.patentes, departamento.idtracto)
        select.append(option)

      })
    }
  })
}
CargarPatente();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar y gracias por tu tiempo y conocimiento.