# ejecutar funciones sql con php

Tags: php, postgresql

Es posible ejecutar funciones creadas en el motor de base de datos de PostgreSQL a través de mi query en PHP?...

Me queda claro que los disparadores se ejecutan en cuanto realizas cambios en las tablas de tu BD, sin embargo, me queda la duda de saber si es posible hacer lo siguiente:

tengo la función suma() creada en el motor de PostgreSQL

```
create or Replace function suma(num1 integer, num2 integer) returns integer
as
$$
select num1 + num2;
$$
Language SQL;
```

lo que intento hacer es en mi editor de codigo y con PHP lo siguiente:

```
$num1 = (isset($_POST['num1'])) ? $_POST['num1']:"";
$num2 = (isset($_POST['num2'])) ? $_POST['num2']:"";
$suma = pg_query($conn,"SELECT suma($num1,$num2)"); <-- aqui llamo la función suma de postgresql
echo $suma;
```

antes de poder introducir las variables me esta arrojando error:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «,» LINE 1: SELECT suma(,) ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\moca\secciones\imagen.php on line 49

Comment: Esto `suma(,)` hace pensar que no estás recibiendo bien los datos. Pon un  `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Si, me lo esta arrojando como string
"array(2) { ["num1"]=> string(1) "1" ["num2"]=> string(1) "3" }"

Ya vi mis inputs tienen el type='number' no entiendo por que los cambia a string

Comment: Eso es así, cuando un form es enviado, sus datos, también numéricos, se serializan como cadenas en la superglobal, pero puedes forzarlos a entero, por ejemplo: `$num1 = (int) $_POST['num1'] ?? 0;`, con `(int)` fuerzas a entero y he usado fusión de null, asignando `0` cuando no haya nada en el post ... más simple y más claro. Haz lo mismo con el otro valor.

Comment: Negativo... me aparece un error distinto


> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PgSql\Result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\moca\secciones\imagen.php:49 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\moca\secciones\imagen.php on line 49

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece ahora?

Comment: es en la linea del "echo $suma;"

Comment: Cámbialo por `var_dump($suma);`, estás en fase de depuración.

Comment: `object(PgSql\Result)#2 (0) { }` esto es lo queme aparece ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. Puedes simplificar la recogida de datos usando el [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (PHP >7) o un operador ternario (PHP <7)
2. Dado que has indicado que los dos parámetros son del tipo `integer` en la signatura de la función `(num1 integer, num2 integer)` **debes forzar una conversión a entero** cuando creas los datos que pasarás a la función. Aunque hayas indicado en un formulario un tipo numérico en los `input`, cuando PHP los recibe los convierte a un tipo `string`, eso lo puedes ver fácilmente haciendo un `var_dump($_POST)`.
3. Dado que, como bien dice [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pg-query.php), `pg_query()` **devuelve un recurso** de resultados de consulta en caso de éxito o `false` en caso de error, no puedes tratar el resultado de la llamada como si fuera una cadena, con un `echo` u otro, sino **usar los métodos de que dispone ese controlador para leer los datos**. Para el caso que nos ocupa, usaremos [`pg_fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-row.php) para leer los datos<sup>1</sup>.

   Dicho sea de paso, la misma documentación **desaconseja el uso de `pg_query()` cuando manejas parámetros externos**, porque suponen un grave riesgo de seguridad en forma de *inyección SQL*<sup>2</sup>. Es mejor usar [`pg_query_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pg-query-params.php), y eso haremos.

Entonces, así debería funcionar:

```
/*
   Recuerda cambiar por operador ternario
   si trabajas en PHP < 7
*/
$num1 = (int) $_POST['num1'] ?? 0;
$num2 = (int) $_POST['num2'] ?? 0;

/*
   Observa la diferencia aquí:
    1. Cambiamos pg_query por pg_query_params
    2. En la consulta, en vez de poner los datos directamente
       ponemos unos marcadores con el formato $N
       y los datos son pasados aparte, en un array
       Esto evitará que te inyecten código dañiño vía SQL
       Para que se vea más claro, puse la consulta
       en una variable llamada $sql
*/

$sql='SELECT suma($1,$2)';           
$suma = pg_query_params($conn, $sql, array($num1, $num2));

/*
   Como ya dijimos, pg_query() y pg_query_params()
   devuelven un recurso. Para leer ese recurso,
   debes usar uno de los métodos que existen para ello
   Agregaremos un control, para verificar que 
   no hubo error en la consulta
*/

if ($suma) 
{
    $row = pg_fetch_row($suma);
    echo $row[0];
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error en la consulta";
}
```

#### Notas:

1. Hay varios métodos de lectura. [Los puedes ver aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php), son todos los que empiezan por `pg_fetch_`.
2. La *inyección SQL* supone un gravísimo problema, y no afecta sólo a los datos, sino que, hay escenarios en los que te pueden colar archivos dañiños en el servidor. Para comprender el alcance de esto puedes ver la pregunta: [¿La Inyección SQL actúa sólo a nivel de la base de datos o el riesgo es aún mayor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967).