# Como rescatar parametros out de procedimiento almacenado en MySql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, stored-procedure, parametros

Esperando se encuentren bien les hago la siguiente consulta,
Necesito recuperar desde un procedimiento almacenado en MySql, con PHP, los parámetros que devuelve, no es un conjunto de filas, es solo un conjunto de parámetros OUT, si lo ejecuto en mysql la llamada es la siguiente:

call sp_detalleventas(1,'2022-10-16',@cajainicial,@ventaboletas,@ventapersonal,@subtotal,@gastos,@total,@ventatotal);

Y me devuelve:

cajainicial ventaboletas    ventapersonal   subtotal    gastos  total   ventatotal
315414      56480           5000            376894      4500    372394  61480

que son los parámetros de salida.

En PHP la llamada la hago de la siguiente manera

$sql = "call sp_detalleventas(".$id_local.",'".$fechahoy."',@cajainicial,@ventaboletas,@ventapersonal,@subtotal,@gastos,@total,@ventatotal)";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

Lo que se asigna a la variable $resultado, es un valor booleano, un 0 o un 1, dependiendo si tuvo éxito la ejecución de la consulta SQL. Lo que no he podido realizar es rescatar el valor de cada parámetro de salida, osea los valores de @cajainicial, @ventaboletas, @ventapersonal, @subtotal, @gastos, @total y @ventatotal.

Para esto he intentado con varias instrucciones de mysqli sin tener éxito, tales como:
mysqli_fetch_assoc
mysqli_fetch_array
mysqli_fetch_row

Pero siempre recibo un mensaje de error como el siguiente:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Ppronto\pprontoppal\recuperadetalleventas.php on line 18

Es por lo anterior que requiero que alguien que haya hecho algo como esto me pueda indicar las instrucciones correctas para obtener el resultado deseado, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: esta un poco escondido en el manual https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-995 , prepare, bind y al execute te rellena las vars

Comment: @aloMalbarez pero el código de OP no es `PDO`, es `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL, una vez llamado y ejecutado el procedimiento almacenado, necesitas ejecutar una segunda instrucción del tipo: `SELECT @outPutOne, @outPutTwo, @outPutN` con todos los parámetros declarados como de salida en el procedimiento almacenado, revisa al respecto [los ejemplos del Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) donde aparece algo como esto:

```
mysql> CALL citycount('JPN', @cities); -- cities in Japan
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @cities;
+---------+
| @cities |
+---------+
|     248 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Si observas, hay una primera consulta, que es el `CALL` y luego una segunda consulta que hace un `SELECT` de los parámetros declarados como de salida.

Por otra parte, considera usar una consulta preparada real, poniendo marcadores (`?`) por cada valor de entrada, y usand `bind_param()` para pasar los valores que tienes en las variables. Actualmente, pasando los valores tal cual al procedimiento almacenado, te pueden inyectar código.

Finalmente, me permito pasar tu código al estilo orientado a objetos, por ser más claro, más moderno y menos verboso, así como establecer algunos controles, para curar el mal de *programación optimista o ingenua*, en la cual se ignoran eventuales errores.

Así debería funcionar, asumiendo que tu SP está bien programada. Si no lo está, nuestro código nos los dirá de todos modos:

```
if ($conn) 
{
    $sql = "call sp_detalleventas(?,?,@cajainicial,@ventaboletas,@ventapersonal,@subtotal,@gastos,@total,@ventatotal);";
    if ( $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql) ) 
    {
        /*
           Si la columna para $id_local es numérica en la BD
           cambia la primera s por una i en 'ss'
           Revisa la doc sobre bind_param al respecto
        */    
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $id_local,$fechahoy);
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) 
        {
            /*
               Hace falta ahora una nueva consulta
               para obtener los parámetros de salida
            */
            $sqlOut="SELECT @cajainicial,@ventaboletas,@ventapersonal,@subtotal,@gastos,@total,@ventatotal;";
            $rs=$conn->query($sqlOut);
            $mData=$rs->fetch_assoc();
        } else 
        {
            $mData=array('error'=>'Error en la ejecución de la consulta');
        }
    } else 
    {
        $mData=array('error'=>'Error preparando la consulta');
    }
} else 
{
    $mData=array('error'=>'No hay conexión');
}
# Prueba del resultado
var_dump($mData);
```

---

#### Enlaces

1. Ver [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), [`bind_param()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) y [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) en el Manual de PHP para comprender cómo escribir consultas preparadas reales.
2. Ver el apartado de [procedimientos almacenados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) en el Manual de PHP.
3. Para comprender el gravísimo peligro que supone la *inyección SQL* y aprender a evitarla en entorno PHP, ver las preguntas siguientes y sus respuestas:

   - *[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)*
   - *[¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/29967)*
   - *[¿La Inyección SQL actúa sólo a nivel de la base de datos o el riesgo es aún mayor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967)*

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, pero sabes que de la consulta, "SELECT @cajainicial,@ventaboletas,@ventapersonal,@subtotal,@gastos,@total,@ventatotal;";" solo me devuelve el primer valor "@cajainicial", y los otros no, si ejecuto el select en mysql los retorna todos por lo que el proc almacenado esta correcto. O es que hay que ejecutar un while para que siga rescatando valores desde la variable $mData ?

Comment: @CarlosYáñez pues no, hice una prueba in situ con dos valores y me los retorna los dos. Convendría ver tu SP, quizá el problema esté ahí.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo solucione, la verdad es que era un tema de la fecha en que buscaba datos y no existían, razón por la cual no retornaba valores, Vuelvo a agradecer la respuesta, ha sido de gran utilidad