# Vincular PHP y MySQL con AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Estoy teniendo un problema al recibir los datos desde mi base de datos y luego enviarlos a mi Javascript con AJAX. Lo que quiero es obtener las respuestas de las preguntas que el usuario ha realizado antes y pasar esas respuestas (las respuestas pueden ser A, B, C o D), a un Javascript para luego realizar un grafico con esas respuestas. El problema es que mi codigo me devuelve un objeto como error. Procedo a brindar mi codigo y los errores que figuran.

El codigo PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Obtener el email almacenado en la sesión
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "******";
$username = "********";
$db_password = "*********";
$dbname = "**************";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);

// Comprobar la conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    error_log("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error); // Agregar error_log
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Definir un valor predeterminado para $resultados
$resultados = array(
    'answer1' => '',
    'answer2' => '',
    'answer3' => '',
    'answer4' => '',
    'answer5' => ''
);

// Realizar la consulta SQL para obtener los resultados del usuario
$sql = "SELECT pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3,pregunta4,pregunta5 FROM gerente_test WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Verificar si se obtuvieron resultados
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Almacenar los resultados en el array
    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Asignar los valores de la consulta a $resultados
        $resultados = array(
            'answer1' => $row['pregunta1'],
            'answer2' => $row['pregunta2'],
            'answer3' => $row['pregunta3'],
            'answer4' => $row['pregunta4'],
            'answer5' => $row['pregunta5']
        );
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = "No se encontraron resultados";
    $response_json = json_encode($response);
}

// Convertir el array a formato JSON
$respuestas_json = json_encode($resultados);
// Enviar la respuesta JSON al cliente
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
$conn->close();
?>
```

El Javascript es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hacer la solicitud AJAX al servidor
    $.ajax({
        url: 'estadistica_gerente.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resultados) {
            // Separar cada respuesta del array
            const answer1 = resultados[0].answer1;
            const answer2 = resultados[1].answer2;
            const answer3 = resultados[2].answer3;
            const answer4 = resultados[3].answer4;
            const answer5 = resultados[4].answer5;

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola. No estás imprimiendo la respuesta. Considera agregar estas dos líneas al final de tu script PHP de este modo: **`echo $respuestas_json;`** y: **`exit();`** Si no funciona, dinos cuál es el error que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con tu código.

En un flujo de este tipo, donde esperas un JSON, debido a lo que indicaste en la petición Ajax:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

No debes **romper el contrato**, cosa que harías si la conexión falla por ejemplo, resolviendo con un:

```
die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
```

Y es que ese `die()` va a producir un JSON no válido, al no ser controlado en la salida. Es decir, si el cliente (Javascript / Ajax) espera un JSON, tú debes emitir en todos los casos, también en los casos de error, un JSON.

Luego, hay mucha confusión en el manejo de los datos y en la lógica en general y problemas de seguridad. Para solventar esa confusión y lo ya dicho en el párrafo anterior, crearemos un array llamado `$outPut` y en él meteremos todo, pero todo lo que pueda ocurrir y al final devolveremos ese array al cliente en forma de JSON, porque fue el contrato que hicimos con él: *te devolveré un JSON en respuesta, pase lo que pase*.

Corregiremos otros fallos, como falta de algunos controles debido a un estilo de programación demasiado optimista que mira para otro lado ante eventuales errores, como que el email no sea enviado.

Y pondremos un parche de seguridad con respecto a riesgos de *Inyección SQL*. Y es que nunca debes pasar a ejecución una consulta que incluya datos proporcionados por el usuario, porque alguien mal intencionado puede usar los datos que recogerías en `$email` para provocar un verdadero desastre en los datos e incluso en el sistema de archivos del servidor <sup>1</sup>.

También, en muchos escenarios no necesitas `num_rows` para saber si hubo filas. Basta con verificar los datos en sí mismos, o verificar el resultado de la llamada a `fetch()` en este caso, que devolverá `null` cuando no haya datos.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

#### PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Obtener el email almacenado en la sesión
    $email = $_SESSION['email'] ?? null;
    #Declaramos nuestro array de salida
    $outPut=array();
    if ($email) {
        // Conexión a la base de datos
        $servername = "******";
        $username = "********";
        $db_password = "*********";
        $dbname = "**************";
        
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);
        
        // Comprobar la conexión
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            error_log("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error); // Agregar error_log
            $outPut['error']='Fallo en la conexión';
        } else {            
            /*
                Realizar la consulta SQL para obtener los resultados del usuario
                Implementaremos consultas preparadas, para neutralizar el riesgo
                de Inyección SQL. Lee sobre el tema no muy tarde, es MUY IMPORTANTE
            */
            
            $sql = "SELECT pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3,pregunta4,pregunta5 FROM gerente_test WHERE email = ?";
            if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
                $stmt->execute();
                
                /* 
                    Vincular variables a la sentencia preparada 
                    Se vincula una variable por cada columna                    
                */
                $stmt->bind_result($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5);
                
                /* 
                    Si no hay filas la llamada a fetch será null
                    esto basta para saber si hay filas, 
                    no hace falta num_rows, el cual, además
                    depende de la configuración del buffer
                    pudiendo dar en ocasiones datos erróneos.
                    Asumo que esperas una sola fila en esta consulta ¿?
                    Si es así, conviene terminar $sql con LIMIT 1
                    Si esperas más de una fila, debes leer los datos
                    dentro de un bucle while para hacer fetch fila por fila                                      
                */
                if( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                    $outPut['data']=array(
                        'answer1' => $a1,
                        'answer2' => $a2,
                        'answer3' => $a3,
                        'answer4' => $a4,
                        'answer5' => $a5
                    );
                } else {
                    $outPut['error']='No se encontraron filas';
                }               
            } else {
                $outPut['error']='Error preparando la consulta';
            }           
            // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
            $conn->close();
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='No enviaste ningún email';
    }
    /*
         Finalmente, aquí enviamos a $outPut
         con lo que sea que haya ocurrido
    */
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($outPut);
    exit(); 
?>
```

---

#### Javascript

Si analizas la lógica seguida en el código PHP, verás que, cuando hubo algún error, pusimos una clave `error` en el array `$outPut`, en cambio, cuando haya datos, pusimos una clave `data` dentro de la cual se encuentra el array de respuestas.

Por otra parte, los datos vendrán en un array simple, cada uno asociado a una clave, por tanto, los índices `0`, `1`, etc, no tienen sentido aquí:

```
const answer1 = resultados[0].answer1;
const answer2 = resultados[1].answer2;
```

Basta con esto:

```
const answer1 = resultados.answer1;
const answer2 = resultados.answer2;
```

Aplicando lo dicho, puedes acoplar la lógica de este modo al recibir la respuesta en el cliente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hacer la solicitud AJAX al servidor
    $.ajax({
        url: 'estadistica_gerente.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resultados) {
            //Primero verificamos si hubo error
            if(resultados.error) {
                //Esto es sólo para prueba, refina luego
                alert(resultados.error);
            } else {
                // Separar cada respuesta del array
                var mData=resultados.data;
                const answer1 = mData.answer1;
                const answer2 = mData.answer2;
                const answer3 = mData.answer3;
                const answer4 = mData.answer4;
                const answer5 = mData.answer5;
            }

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

De este modo debería funcionar, salvo otros errores fuera de este alcance.

Si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios... **Soy Humano, no soy una IA**

---

#### Notas

1. Sobre el enorme alcance de la *Inyección SQL* puedes consultar las respuestas a la paregunta: *[¿La Inyección SQL actúa sólo a nivel de la base de datos o el riesgo es aún mayor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967)*

Comment: @Zerotet lee al final de la respuesta. Pienso ponerlo siempre, dada la posible invasión de respuestas basadas en IA.

Comment: Sus respuestas están tan bien estructuradas que entiendo lo de la nota final.