# consulta sql en php no funciona en un servidor en la nube pero si local

Tags: php

Resulta que tengo este archivo php y me funciona perfectamemte de manera local pero al ponerlo en un hosting no me funciona y me envia este error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getSQLResultSet()" la version de php es PHP: 5.6.30

```
    <?php
include('DatabaseConfig.php');
$id=$_GET["id"];


if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE id='$id'")){
    while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Donde estás declarando getSQLResultSet() ?

Comment: ok voy a revisar eso

Comment: El te esta diciendo que esa función no esta definida, y buscando en google no encuentro nada sobre una función que se llame así, lo cual debes mirar si te está haciendo falta subir algún archivo al servidor

Comment: Exactamente era eso muchas gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/250) y [cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250). El código que compartes presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad, puede sufrir de este tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en un entorno de producción.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes otra medalla ! saludos.

Comment: gracias a todos tendre muy encuenta sus recomendaciones