# where dinámico (con variable dinámica)

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un PHP con un query MYSQL como el que sigue, pero no funciona. El problema es que no tiene en cuenta el where.

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("select fecha, numero from garantia where (fecha>='$a00' and fecha<='$a01') and $a10");
```

Los valores para comparar fechas vienen correctos.

El inconveniente está en `$a10`, ya que si la elimino, funciona todo perfecto. el valor de `$a10` es correcto, en particular es `$a10 = "proveedor = 'JUAN PEREZ S.A.'";`

Les agradeceré cualquier ayuda que me oriente, ya que no sé cómo cambiar la notación, o lo que sea.
Muchas gracias !

Comment: Advertencia: [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla)

Comment: te marca un error o qué es lo que ocurre?

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo tu estructuración y tus métodos , podrías probar algo como esto:

```
$query = "select fecha, numero from garantia where (fecha>='$a00' and fecha<='$a01') and ".$a10;
$result2 = mysql_query ($query);
```

Es tan solo concatenar la variable $a10 a la query.Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Perfecto !!!! Muchísimas gracias Marcos !

Comment: De nada , no olvides marcar como respuesta por si alguien le pasa lo mismo que a ti , para que vaya directamente aqui . :)