# error de sintaxis

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

lo que pasa es que estoy intentado insertar los datos enviados por php pero me sale error de sintaxis:

> on Tutela Poso no no n 2018-02-14 112345 Sociedad Clinica Emcosalud sigue intentando 98765432 Cedula de Ciudada ni aproblemas en el selectYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on','on','on','Tutela Pos','on','2018-02-14','112345','Sociedad Clinica Emcosalu' at line 4

### esta es la consulta:

```
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_tickets")or
die ("problemas con la conexion");


$authorization = $_REQUEST['authorization'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$formula = $_REQUEST['formula'];
$history  = $_REQUEST['history'];
$document = $_REQUEST['document'];
$authorization_date = $_REQUEST['authorization_date'];
$document_number = $_REQUEST['document_number'];
$entity = $_REQUEST['entity'];
$authorization_number = $_REQUEST['authorization_number'];
$observations = $_REQUEST['observations'];
$document_type = $_REQUEST['document_type'];

echo $authorization, $type, $formula, $history, $document, $authorization_date, $document_number, $entity, $observations, $authorization_number, $document_type;

mysqli_query($conexion,

"INSERT INTO 
guardianship(type,authorization,formula,history,document,authorization_date,document_number,entity,
observations)
VALUES ($_REQUEST[authorization]','$_REQUEST[formula]','$_REQUEST[history]','$_REQUEST[type]','$_REQUEST[document]','$_REQUEST[authorization_date]','$_REQUEST[document_number]','$_REQUEST[entity]','$_REQUEST[observations]',NOW())") or

die ("problemas en el select".mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO medical_record(id,number,guardianship_id)
VALUES ('$_REQUEST[id]',
'$_REQUEST[number]',
'$_REQUEST[guardianship_id]'") or

die ("problemas en el select".mysqli_error($conexion))

//mysqli_close($conexion);

//echo'<script language="JavaScript"> alert("Registro Exitoso");</script>';*/
?>
```

### esta es la tabla

```
id 
type
authorization
formula
history
document
authorization_date
document_type
document_number
entity
observations
status
user
```

Comment: podrías compartir la tabla a la que intentas hacer el insert y la consulta

Comment: Hola Toli Soft, lee [ask] y [answer], y recuerda que cuando tengas nueva información que añadir debes [edit] la pregunta en lugar de escribir una respuesta. Stack Overflow es un sitio de Q&A y no funciona como un foro.

Comment: Lee sobre [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/250) y [cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250). El código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en entornos de producción.

Comment: Te hace falta una comilla simple en `VALUES ($_REQUEST[authorization]' ` y sigue todas las recomendaciones de los usuarios! también podría ser que estés intentando enviar datos a tu BD que no acepte por el formato de los mismos

Comment: Revisa la forma en que estás programando y hazlo de una forma coherente. Si ya almacenaste los valores de cada `REQUEST`, arriba, ¿por qué cuando necesitas esos datos vuelves a usar `REQUEST`.? También, como ha dicho Álvaro, considera dar seguridad a tu código implementando consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

Además de los comentarios anteriores, tienes otro fallo, y es que los campos de la insert no se corresponden:
INSERT INTO 
guardianship(**type**,authorization,formula,history,document,authorization_date,document_number,entity,
observations)
VALUES ($_REQUEST[authorization]','$_REQUEST[formula]','$_RE

Te falta el primer campo type en los values...