# ¿Alguien puede decirme el fallo de mi consulta mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Mi error es que al enviar el formulario envia el echo pero no guarda la insercion de sqlm si pueden ayudarme lo agradeceria.

```
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
$snombre = $_POST["snombre"];
$stel = $_POST["stel"];
$semail = $_POST["semail"];
$scasilla1=$_POST['scasilla1'];
$scasilla2=$_POST["scasilla2"];
$scasilla3=$_POST["scasilla3"];
$scasilla4=$_POST["scasilla4"];
$scasilla5=$_POST["scasilla5"];
$scasilla6=$_POST["scasilla6"];
$scasilla7=$_POST["scasilla7"];
$scasilla8=$_POST["scasilla8"];
$scasilla9=$_POST["scasilla9"];

$con->query("INSERT INTO servicios (snombre, stel, semail, scasilla1, 
scasilla2, scasilla3, scasilla4, scasilla5, scasilla6, scasilla7,   
scasilla8,  scasilla9)  

VALUES('$snombre','$stel','$semail','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')");

 echo "Se ha enviado de manera satisfactoria.<a   
 href='servicios.php'>Volver<a/>";
 }
mysqli_close($con);
```

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Raul, lee sobre [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/250) y [cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250). El código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse de cara al público.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos con los siguientes cambios ya debería insertar:

las variables se meten en la siguiente sintáxis

```
'".$variable."'
```

Otro detalle no veo donde esta tu archivo de conexión o la función que te conecta al servidor

En tu código veo una variable llamada $con que tiene el acceso a  la BD pero en ningún lado de tu código se observa o la función o el require a un archivo .php externo que contenga dicha conexión

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "base_datos_hospital");//como mero ejemplo

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
$snombre = $_POST["snombre"];
$stel = $_POST["stel"];
$semail = $_POST["semail"];
$scasilla1=$_POST['scasilla1'];
$scasilla2=$_POST["scasilla2"];
$scasilla3=$_POST["scasilla3"];
$scasilla4=$_POST["scasilla4"];
$scasilla5=$_POST["scasilla5"];
$scasilla6=$_POST["scasilla6"];
$scasilla7=$_POST["scasilla7"];
$scasilla8=$_POST["scasilla8"];
$scasilla9=$_POST["scasilla9"];

$con->query = "INSERT INTO servicios (snombre, stel, semail, scasilla1, 
scasilla2, scasilla3, scasilla4, scasilla5, scasilla6, scasilla7,   
scasilla8,  scasilla9)  

VALUES('".$snombre."','".$stel."','".$semail."','".$scasilla1."','".$scasilla2."','".$scasilla3."','".$scasilla4."','".$scasilla5."','".$scasilla6."','".$scasilla7."','".$scasilla8."','".$scasilla9."')";

 echo "Se ha enviado de manera satisfactoria.<a   
 href='servicios.php'>Volver<a/>";
 }
mysqli_close($con);
```

Prueba y nos comentas

Comment: El problema persiste sigue sin entrar en la base de datos, incluso quitando los parentesis inciales de sql

Comment: checa lo que coloque en mi respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias esta bien ahora

Comment: si te sirve me la pudieras calificar por favor?

Comment: lo haria gustosamente pero nunca he usado este foro y nose como se hace, si eres tan amable de decirmelo

Comment: listo ya le di muchas gracias, por cierto abri otra pregunta de encriptacion por si sabes algo de eso me ayudaria para encriptar mi password de la BD

Comment: deja busco tu publicación y si puedo con gusto te ayudo

Comment: muchisimas gracias, un saludo