# Como ordenar los id de mayor a menor

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito mostrar los datos del ultimo que se subió al ultimo por medio del id.
pero la consulta que tengo me muestra del primero al ultimo.

```
function obtener_post_por_id($conexion, $id){
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
    $resultado = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return ($resultado) ? $resultado : false;
}
```

Comment: Hola, creo que la pregunta debería decir _"del ultimo que se subió al primero"_..., por otro lado el `WHERE id = $id` indica que solo quieres obtener el elemento con el _id_ igual a `$id` y el `LIMIT 1` indica que solo quieres un elemento, ¿lo que quieres es solamente mostrar tu tabla ordenada? para eso solo bastaba un `SELECT * FROM articulos order by id desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes utilizar `ORDER BY` que te permite ordenar los registros arrojados de tu consulta. En especifico como necesitas el último registro ingresado es conveniente utilizar `ORDER BY id DESC` que significa ordena según el campo `id` de mayor a menor, es decir, que seleccionarías desde el último registro ingresado (porque ya tienes LIMIT 1 que indica que traiga un sólo registro como resultado)

Entonces tu sentencia sql quedaría:

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
```

y tu código con la mejora quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
function obtener_post_por_id($conexion, $id){
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $resultado = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return ($resultado) ? $resultado : false;
}
```

**Observación:** No es recomendable pasar los datos directamente a tu consulta sin previamente haberlos "escapado" correctamente para evitar fallos en la seguridad de tu aplicación. Puedes leer más sobre lo que te comento aquí: [que es la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla) y [pasos para evitar la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233)

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar dentro de un QUERY MYSQL, puedes utilizar el ORDER BY para especificar la columna que deseas que ordene los registros y de ahí ponerle un ASC o DESC al final para que los traiga ASCENDENTE o DESCENDENTE según necesites.

```
"SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Sería más o menos lo que necesitarías para obtener los datos del modo que necesitas

*EDICIÓN, como bien menciona @the-breaker debe ser DESC, me confundí con la primera frase de la pregunta.

Comment: @the-breaker Gracias por la observación me confudí con lo que dice que necesita de "Necesito mostrar los datos del ultimo que se subió al ultimo por medio del id".

Comment: no hay problema, esta pregunta esta mal formulada <strike>por si acaso ese -1 no es mio</strike>

Comment: No hay problema jaja, entiendo que me equivoqué y alguien pues considera que merece un -1, aunque si se ve un poco severo.