# Asignar dos variables a una ruta en $_FILES PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

Tengo el siguiente código para guardar archivos en php, funciona correctamente, me crea bien la ruta con el id correspondiente

```
        $permitidos = array("application/pdf");     
        $limite_kb = 8360;

        if(in_array($_FILES["acta"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["acta"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

          $ruta = '../../files/personas/proyectos/actas/'.$id_persona.'/';
          $acta = $ruta.$_FILES["acta"]["name"];

          if(!file_exists($ruta)){

              mkdir($ruta);
          }

          if(!file_exists($acta)){

              $resultado1 = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["acta"]["tmp_name"], $acta);



          } else{

              $actaErr= "El archivo ya existe";
              $valid = false;
          }
        } else{
          $actaErr= "Formato no valido o el archivo sobrepasa el tamaño permitido. Solo se aceptan archivos PDF y el tamaño máximo que puede enviar es de 8 MB";
          $valid = false;
        }

      }else{
          $actaErr= "Ups! El acta de asamblea es obligatoria";
          $valid = false;
      }
```

Pero quiero agregar una carpeta más después de `$id_persona` con el `$id_proyecto`
intenté así pero me manda el error `Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory`

```
 $ruta = '../../files/personas/proyectos/actas_asamblea/'.$id_persona.'/'.$id_proyecto.'/';
```

Comment: El tercer parámetro de [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php) hace que se creen las subcarpetas recursivamente si no existen. Es mas o menos lo que se plantea en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/173540/81450

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como crear una carpeta automáticamente cuando un usuario se registra en mi web?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173537/como-crear-una-carpeta-autom%c3%a1ticamente-cuando-un-usuario-se-registra-en-mi-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pongamos un ejemplo en el que `$id_persona` no existe. Como accedes a `id_proyecto`?

Tendrás que comprobar primero si existe la ruta `$id_persona` para luego crear `$id_proyecto`

```
$ruta = '../../files/personas/proyectos/actas/'.$id_persona.'/';

if(!file_exists($ruta)){
   mkdir($ruta);
}
$ruta = '../../files/personas/proyectos/actas/'.$id_persona.'/'.$id_proyecto.'';

if(!file_exists($ruta)){
   mkdir($ruta);
}

$acta = $ruta.$_FILES["acta"]["name"];
```

De esta manera, primero compruebas si existe el directorio `$id_persona` y si no existe lo creas, luego compruebas `$id_proyecto` y si no existe lo creas.

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, sigue el mismo error

Comment: Hice algunos cambios en base a tu respuesta, cambie el nombre de la segunda $ruta por $ruta2 y agregué la diagonal faltante en la segunda ruta, muchas gracias!