# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema con el formulario de cambio de contraseña, al momento de cambiar me lanza el error que está en la imagen para encriptar estoy usando este tipo de hash que me genera contraseñas de este tipo $2y$10$pGHOAJxCHmqSltaHTwwxvuuWxEV3Cuh7jRMhS7fNCJ41QG4WZ6z/2 el problema es que al momento de actualizar la contraseña me lanza ese error y no reconoce la contraseña $old que sería la que tengo actualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Linea 21 : if(password_verify($old, $row['password'])){**

Porque que será que sucede esto y que podría hacer para solucionarlo de ante mano gracias.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    // obtener datos POST
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];
    $retype = $_POST['retype'];

    //crear una sesión para los datos en caso de que ocurra un error
    $_SESSION['old'] = $old;
    $_SESSION['new'] = $new;
    $_SESSION['retype'] = $retype;

    // obtener detalles del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id_admin = '".$_SESSION['auth']."'";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

    //comprobar si la contraseña anterior es correcta
    if(password_verify($old, $row['password'])){
        // comprueba si la nueva contraseña coincide, vuelve a escribir

        if($new == $retype){
            //hash contraseña

            $password = password_hash($new, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            //actualiza la nueva contraseña
            $sql = "UPDATE admin SET password = '$password' WHERE id_admin = '".$_SESSION['auth']."'";
            if($con->query($sql)){
                $msg = "Contraseña actualizada exitosamente";

               //desarmar nuestra sesión ya que no ocurrió ningún error
                unset($_SESSION['old']);
                unset($_SESSION['new']);
                unset($_SESSION['retype']);
            }
            else{
                $error = $con->error;
            }
        }
        else{
            $error = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
        }
    }
    else{
        $error = "Contraseña antigua incorrecta";
    }
}
else{
    $error = "Ingrese los datos necesarios para actualizar primero";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 21?

Comment: Linea 21 : if(password_verify($old, $row['password'])){

Comment: Al parecer `$row` es null ahí. Depúralo poniendo un `var_dump($row);` justo debajo de donde lo creas y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: dirty fix `if(password_verify($old, ($row['password']??'nohaypassword' ))){`

Comment: NULL try to access array offset on value of type null in Linea 22

Comment: Pues eso, `$row`  es `NULL` y mientras sea `NULL` nada que hacer. Depura tu variable de sesión y depura tu post con `var_dump($_SESSION);` y con `var_dump($_POST);` haz también un `echo $sql;` , copia y pega el resultado y verifica si hay registros con ese criterio en tu base de datos. Tu gran problema aquí es lo que yo llamo *programación optimista*. Tú asumes que: 1. La conexión funciona; 2. La consulta trae datos ... pasas a usar esos datos, pero ¡No existen esos datos! Debes comprobar todo lo que puede fallar para controlarlo. Te faltan esos dos controles, no seas optimista en ese punto.

Comment: Tal cual como dice el compañoer A Cedano, la consulta no está devolviendo ningun resultado, o sea retorna NULL, estas intentando acceder a la propiedad password de NULL (de ahi el error). Por otro lado, realizar consultas a la base de datos concatenando los parametros es una muy mala práctica y puede dejar el sistema vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Más info aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla