# Inconveniente al pasar datos a mi BD de MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Buen día, tengo este inconveniente. Estoy intentando pasar datos a mi base de datos MySQL con Python, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, adjunto mi código:

```
@app.route('/Anzoateguis', methods=['POST'])
def agregar_municipio():
    try:
        cursor = conexion.connection.cursor()        
        sql = "INSERT INTO anzoategui (nombre, latitud, longitud)" Values ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}')"(request.json['nombre'],request.json['latitud'],request.json['longitud'])
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conexion.connection.commit()       
        return jsonify({'mensaje': 'municipio registrado.'})
    except Exception as ex:
          return jsonify({'mensaje':'Error'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Este SQL está mal:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO anzoategui (nombre...)" Values ('{1}'...)"(request...)
#                                Aqui ---^                  ^--- Aqui
```

Hay una comilla doble de más, y posiblemente falta un `.format()`. Si usas el `str.format()` con reemplazo posicional, entonces debe empezar por `0`. Quedaría así:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO anzoategui (nombre, latitud, longitud) Values \
('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')".format(request.json['nombre'], \
request.json['latitud'], request.json['longitud'])
```

Sin embargo ese código es vulnerable a [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/80870), por lo que mejor sale:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO anzoategui (nombre, latitud, longitud) Values (%s, %s, %s)"
data = (request.json['nombre'], request.json['latitud'], request.json['longitud'])
cursor.execute(sql, data)
conexion.connection.commit()
```