# error al descargar archivo .jpg del Servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches estimados.

Estoy teniendo problemas con la descarga de archivos de imagen o pdf, ya que en mi localhost me anda perfectamente, pero cuando lo subo al hosting no funciona y no entiendo el porqué.

Lo que sucede es que no descarga el archivo y muestra una página con símbolos.
Lo que hago es obtener la ruta almacenada en la bd y con esa ruta fuerzo la descarga.

Copio el código que "ejecuta" la descarga y la imágen del error que me devuelve.

Agradezco mucho si alguien me puede ayudar a resolverlo.

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<?php
  include ("../Conexion/conexion.php");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM licespec";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

  $files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


 if (isset($_GET['file_id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['file_id'];


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM licespec WHERE idSolic=$id";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

  $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $filepath = $file['ruta'];

  if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file['ruta']); 
   } 
 }
```

?>

[image: Erro de descarga:]

Comment: Para pdf el tipo de contenido debería ser `application/pdf` para que el navegador lo muestre apropiadamente.

Comment: Debería considerar usar "sentencias preparadas" para evitar [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que lo que debe estar generando el error es la apertura y cerrado del `PHP` después del `session_start();`.

¿Por que?
Se esta agregando un salto de línea y esto provoca que la función `header` deje de hacer su trabajo.

#### Solución:

Sacarlos, no hacen falta.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<?php
  session_start();

  include ("../Conexion/conexion.php");
  // ... resto del código
```

**PD:** Tampoco hace falta cerrar `PHP` si debajo no hay nada mas.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, he probado tu sugerencia pero no me ha funcionado, el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: @Hugo, debes hacer lo que te dice Marcos en TODOS los archivos PHP. Con que uno de ellos mande un espacio en blanco que haya antes de una apertura de PHP, un retorno del carro después del cierre, etc provoca que no se puedan enviar las cabeceras al navegador. Por favor, revisa las recomendaciones, por ejemplo, en el archivo `conexion.php`. Además, veo que usas un `ob_clean()`, ¿en qué momento haces el `ob_start()`? Si vas a usarlo, debería ser la primera instrucción del código PHP, incluso antes del `session_start()`.

Comment: Marcos, @Oscar, gracias por sus sugerencias y aportes, me han sido de gran ayuda. Quité todos los espacios en blanco de todos los archivos involucrados en el proceso de descarga y funcionó perfectamente. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Me alegra saber que arreglaste tu problema. Te sugiero que marques la respuesta de Marcos como correcta para dar por solucionada esta pregunta.

Comment: Si @Oscar, soy nuevo y desconocía que debía darle correcta a la respuesta. Gracias a ambos.