# ¿Como evito que al actualizar un registro se cree uno completamente nuevo en php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

me encuentro realizando un administrador tipo CRUD de donde actualmente estoy programando un modulo de Contactos, sin embargo me he encontrado con el problema de que al tratar de actualizar un registro ya existente, se crea uno completamente nuevo, no comprendo porque me sucede esta situación ya que me base en el mismo código que use para otro modulo con la misma funcionalidad llamado Organizacion, el cual funciona perfectamente, he checado detenidamente el código ya varias veces y no encuentro el error sobre el porque no permite actualizarce ya que he procurado respetar toda la sintaxis y estructura que esta en mi conocimiento.

Explico la estructura de cada uno de mis modulos: Cada modulo CRUD lo he realizado con el MVC por lo que dividi las acciones de cada modulo en 4 archivos distintos: una clase modelo, un ajax, un script y una vista, adjunto los codigos de los mismos.

Estare al pendiente si no he aclarado bien algo, sin mas que expresar, Gracias de antemano

```
    Class Contacto
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    //Implementamos un método para insertar registros
    public function insertar($id_organizacion,$telefono_1,$telefono_2,$extenciones,$ext_pais_cel,$celular,$correo_1,$correo_2)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO contacto (id_organizacion,telefono_1,telefono_2,extenciones,ext_pais_cel,celular,correo_1,correo_2,condicion)
        VALUES ('$id_organizacion','$telefono_1','$telefono_2','$extenciones','$ext_pais_cel','$celular','$correo_1','$correo_2','1')";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }

    //Implementamos un método para editar registros
    public function editar($id_contacto,$id_organizacion,$telefono_1,$telefono_2,$extenciones,$ext_pais_cel,$celular,$correo_1,$correo_2)
    {
        $sql="UPDATE contacto SET id_organizacion='$id_organizacion',telefono_1='$telefono_1',telefono_2='$telefono_2',extenciones='$extenciones',ext_pais_cel='$ext_pais_cel',celular='$celular',correo_1='$correo_1',correo_2='$correo_2' WHERE id_contacto='$id_contacto'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }

    //Implementar un método para mostrar los datos de un registro a modificar
    public function mostrar($id_contacto)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM contacto WHERE id_contacto='$id_contacto'";
        return ejecutarConsultaSimpleFila($sql);
    }


    //Implementamos un método para desactivar registros
    public function desactivar($id_contacto)
    {
        $sql="UPDATE contacto SET condicion='0' WHERE id_contacto='$id_contacto'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }

    //Implementamos un método para activar registros
    public function activar($id_contacto)
    {
        $sql="UPDATE contacto SET condicion='1' WHERE id_contacto='$id_contacto'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }


    //Implementar un método para listar los registros
    public function listar()
    {
        $sql="SELECT a.id_contacto,c.id_organizacion, c.nombre as organizacion,a.telefono_1,a.telefono_2,a.extenciones,a.ext_pais_cel,a.celular,a.correo_1,a.correo_2, a.condicion FROM contacto a INNER JOIN organizacion c ON a.id_organizacion=c.id_organizacion";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);      
    }
}

?>
```

A continuacion el codigo del ajax

```
    <?php 
require_once "../modelos/Contacto.php";

$contacto=new Contacto();

$id_contacto=isset($_POST["id_contacto"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["id_contacto"]):"";
$id_organizacion=isset($_POST["id_organizacion"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["id_organizacion"]):"";
$telefono_1=isset($_POST["telefono_1"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["telefono_1"]):"";
$telefono_2=isset($_POST["telefono_2"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["telefono_2"]):"";
$extenciones=isset($_POST["extenciones"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["extenciones"]):"";
$ext_pais_cel=isset($_POST["ext_pais_cel"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["ext_pais_cel"]):"";
$celular=isset($_POST["celular"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["celular"]):"";
$correo_1=isset($_POST["correo_1"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["correo_1"]):"";
$correo_2=isset($_POST["correo_2"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["correo_2"]):"";


switch ($_GET["op"]){
    case 'guardaryeditar':
        if (empty($id_contacto)){
            $rspta=$contacto->insertar($id_organizacion,$telefono_1,$telefono_2,$extenciones,$ext_pais_cel,$celular,$correo_1,$correo_2);
            echo $rspta ? "Contacto registrado" : "Contacto no se pudo registrar";
        }
        else {
            $rspta=$contacto->editar($id_contacto,$id_organizacion,$telefono_1,$telefono_2,$extenciones,$ext_pais_cel,$celular,$correo_1,$correo_2);
            echo $rspta ? "Contacto actualizado" : "Contacto no se pudo actualizar";
        }
    break;

    case 'mostrar':
        $rspta=$contacto->mostrar($id_contacto);
        //Codificar el resultado utilizando json
        echo json_encode($rspta);
        break;
    break;

    case 'desactivar':
        $rspta=$contacto->desactivar($id_contacto);
        echo $rspta ? "Contacto Desactivada" : "Contacto no se puede desactivar";
        break;
    break;

    case 'activar':
        $rspta=$contacto->activar($id_contacto);
        echo $rspta ? "Contacto activado" : "Contacto no se puede activar";
        break;
    break;

    case 'listar':
        $rspta=$contacto->listar();
        //Vamos a declarar un array
        $data= Array();

        while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
            $data[]=array(
                "0"=>($reg->condicion)?'<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->id_contacto.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.
                    ' <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="desactivar('.$reg->id_contacto.')"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>':
                    '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="mostrar('.$reg->id_contacto.')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'.
                    ' <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="activar('.$reg->id_contacto.')"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>',
                "1"=>$reg->organizacion,
                "2"=>$reg->telefono_1,
                "3"=>$reg->telefono_2,
                "4"=>$reg->extenciones,
                "5"=>$reg->ext_pais_cel,
                "6"=>$reg->celular,
                "7"=>$reg->correo_1,
                "8"=>$reg->correo_2,
                "9"=>($reg->condicion)?'<span class="label bg-green">Activado</span>':
                '<span class="label bg-red">Desactivado</span>'
                );
        }
        $results = array(
            "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
            "aaData"=>$data);
        echo json_encode($results);

    break;

    case "selectOrganizacion":
        require_once "../modelos/Articulo.php";
        $organizacion = new Organizacion();

        $rspta = $organizacion->select();

        while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object())
                {
                    echo '<option value=' . $reg->id_organizacion . '>' . $reg->nombre . '</option>';
                }
    break;
}
?>
```

El javscript

```
var tabla;

//Función que se ejecuta al inicio
function init(){
    mostrarform(false);
    listar();

    $("#formulario").on("submit",function(e)
    {
        guardaryeditar(e);  
    })

    //Cargamos los items al select categoria
    $.post("../ajax/contacto.php?op=selectOrganizacion", function(r){
                $("#id_organizacion").html(r);
                $('#id_organizacion').selectpicker('refresh');

    });
}

//Función limpiar
function limpiar()
{
    $("#telefono_1").val("");
    $("#telefono_2").val("");
    $("#extenciones").val("");
    $("#ext_pais_cel").val("");
    $("#celular").val("");
    $("#correo_1").val("");
    $("#correo_2").val("");
}

//Función mostrar formulario
function mostrarform(flag)
{
    limpiar();
    if (flag)
    {
        $("#listadoregistros").hide();
        $("#formularioregistros").show();
        $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",false);
        $("#btnagregar").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#listadoregistros").show();
        $("#formularioregistros").hide();
        $("#btnagregar").show();
    }
}

//Función cancelarform
function cancelarform()
{
    limpiar();
    mostrarform(false);
}

//Función Listar
function listar()
{
    tabla=$('#tbllistado').dataTable(
    {
        "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
        "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
        dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
        buttons: [                
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdf'
                ],
        "ajax":
                {
                    url: '../ajax/contacto.php?op=listar',
                    type : "get",
                    dataType : "json",                      
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e.responseText);    
                    }
                },
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,//Paginación
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]//Ordenar (columna,orden)
    }).DataTable();
}
//Función para guardar o editar

function guardaryeditar(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //No se activará la acción predeterminada del evento
    $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",true);
    var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/contacto.php?op=guardaryeditar",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(datos)
        {                    
              bootbox.alert(datos);           
              mostrarform(false);
              tabla.ajax.reload();
        }

    });
    limpiar();
}

function mostrar(id_contacto)
{
    $.post("../ajax/contacto.php?op=mostrar",{id_contacto : id_contacto}, function(data, status)
    {
        data = JSON.parse(data);        
        mostrarform(true);

        $("#id_organizacion").val(data.id_organizacion);
        $('#id_organizacion').selectpicker('refresh');
        $("#telefono_1").val(data.telefono_1);
        $("#telefono_2").val(data.telefono_2);
        $("#extenciones").val(data.extenciones);
        $("#ext_pais_cel").val(data.ext_pais_cel);
        $("#celular").val(data.celular);
        $("#correo_1").val(data.correo_1);
        $("#correo_2").val(data.correo_2);

    })
}

//Función para desactivar registros
function desactivar(id_contacto)
{
    bootbox.confirm("¿Está Seguro de desactivar el contacto", function(result){
        if(result)
        {
            $.post("../ajax/contacto.php?op=desactivar", {id_contacto : id_contacto}, function(e){
                bootbox.alert(e);
                tabla.ajax.reload();
            }); 
        }
    })
}

//Función para activar registros
function activar(id_contacto)
{
    bootbox.confirm("¿Está Seguro de activar el contacto", function(result){
        if(result)
        {
            $.post("../ajax/contacto.php?op=activar", {id_contacto : id_contacto}, function(e){
                bootbox.alert(e);
                tabla.ajax.reload();
            }); 
        }
    })
}

init();
```

y finalmente la vista

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>
<!--Contenido-->
      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">        
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                          <h1 class="box-title">Contacto <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnagregar" onclick="mostrarform(true)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar</button></h1>
                        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive" id="listadoregistros">
                        <table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Organizacion</th>
                            <th>Telefono 1</th>
                            <th>Telefono 2</th>
                            <th>Extenciones</th>
                            <th>Extencion de Celular por Pais</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>Correo 1</th>
                            <th>Correo 2</th>
                            <th>Actividad</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>                            
                          </tbody>
                          <tfoot>
                          <th>Opciones</th>
                            <th>Organizacion</th>
                            <th>Telefono 1</th>
                            <th>Telefono 2</th>
                            <th>Extenciones</th>
                            <th>Extencion de Celular por Pais</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>Correo 1</th>
                            <th>Correo 2</th>
                            <th>Actividad</th>
                          </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="formularioregistros">
                        <form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Organizacion(*):</label>
                            <select id="id_organizacion" name="id_organizacion" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required></select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Telefono 1(*):</label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_contacto" id="id_contacto">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_1" id="telefono_1" maxlength="12" placeholder="telefono_1" required>
                            <label>Telefono 2:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono_2" id="telefono_2" maxlength="12" placeholder="telefono_2" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Extenciones:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extenciones" id="extenciones" maxlength="256" placeholder="Extenciones">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Extencion de Celular por Pais:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ext_pais_cel" id="ext_pais_cel" maxlength="256" placeholder="ext_pais_cel">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Celular:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="celular" id="celular" maxlength="256" placeholder="Celular">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Correo 1:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="correo_1" id="correo_1" maxlength="256" placeholder="Correo 1">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label>Correo 2:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="correo_2" id='correo_2' maxlength="256" placeholder="Correo 2">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnGuardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelarform()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--Fin centro -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->
              </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </section><!-- /.content -->

    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!--Fin-Contenido-->
<?php
require 'footer.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.PrintArea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/contacto.js"></script>
```

Comment: Comprueba que `limpiarCadena($_POST["id_contacto"])` no esté arrojando algo vacio

Comment: Diría que el problema estan en la función `mostrar(id_contacto)`. Al recibir la respuesta con los datos del contacto, se te ha olvidado guardar el `id_contacto` en el `<input type="hidden" name="id_contacto"/>`. **PD:** la función `limpiar` tiene el "mismo" problema, no se te tiene que olvidar limpiar dicho `input`.

Comment: Otra cosa, te aconsejo resivar [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/16597) y [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597)

Comment: @Marcos he realizado los cambios que me mencionas, he checado mostrar  y limpiar y las he corregido sin embargo no he logrado que edite

Comment: @Yussef como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: @Marcos Gracias por la info sobre la inyección he adquirido una nueva perspectiva a diferente a la manera en que aprendi a programar