# Error en la inserción de datos

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo un problema a la hora de poder insertar mis datos dentro de mi base de datos en la table articulos, me aparece este error: ``Las columnas de tipo 'DOUBLE' no pueden contener valores de tipo 'CHAR'`. No sé muy bien porque ocurre. Me encuentro trabajando con una *arquitectura por capas*.

Mi **table** articulo es la siguiente:

```
create table articulo(
 cod char(4) not null,
 nom varchar(40) not null,
 pre double not null,
 sto int not null,
 primary key (cod)
)
```

Este es mi `DaoArticuloImp`, en lo que respecta a la clase que dice `Operación` esa si funciona bien, ya lo habia probado anteriormente y funcionaba sin ningún problema.

```
public class DaoArticuloImp implements DaoArticulo{

@Override
public String grabar(String cod, String nom, double pre, int sto) {
    String sql ="insert into articulo values('"+cod+"','"+nom+"','"+pre+"','"+sto+"')";
    return Operacion.ejecutar(sql);
}

@Override
public Object[] buscar(String cod) {
    String sql = "select * from articulo where cod='"+cod+"'";
    return Operacion.buscar(sql);
}

@Override
public String actualizar(String cod, double pre, int sto) {
    String sql = "update articulo set pre='"+pre+"' and sto='"+sto+"' where cod='"+cod+"'";
    return Operacion.ejecutar(sql);
}

@Override
public String eliminar(String cod) {
    String sql = "delete from articulo where cod='"+cod+"'";
    return Operacion.ejecutar(sql);
}

@Override
public List Listar() {
    String sql = "select * from articulo";
    return Operacion.listar(sql);
}
}
```

Este es mi `ServicioArticuloImp`:

```
public class ServicioArticuloImp implements ServicioArticulo{
private DaoArticulo da = new DaoArticuloImp();

@Override
public String grabar(String cod, String nom, double pre, int sto) {
    String msg = da.grabar(cod, nom, pre, sto);
    if(msg == null){
        msg="Articulo Grabado";
    }
    return msg;
}

@Override
public Object[] buscar(String cod) {
    return da.buscar(cod);
}

@Override
public String actualizar(String cod, double pre, int sto) {
    String msg = da.actualizar(cod, pre, sto);
    if(msg == null){
        msg="Articulo Actualizado";
    }
    return msg;
}

@Override
public String eliminar(String cod) {
    String msg = da.eliminar(cod);
    if(msg == null){
        msg="Articulo Eliminado";
    }
    return msg;
}

@Override
public List Listar() {
    return da.Listar();
}

}
```

Y esta es mi clase `prueba`, en donde me aparece error, la conexión a la base de datos funciona, pero la inserción de los datos, no.

```
public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    if(new Conexion().getConexion()!=null){
        System.out.println("Si");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    
    ServicioArticulo sa = new ServicioArticuloImp();
    String msg = sa.grabar("C001","PAN",2,2);
    System.out.println(msg);
}

}
```

Comment: @Benito-B y no ocurre sólo con `pre`, sino también con `sto`, el cual es de tipo `int` en la tabla. La cadena debería ser declarada así: `String sql ="insert into articulo values('"+cod+"','"+nom+"',"+pre+","+sto+")";` PERO, todavía eso no es suficiente. La solución segura y sólida en todo aquí es usar **consultas preparadas**. Más bien, que no funcione ahora es una buena noticia, porque si dejas funcionando este código así tienes abierto en el código un enorme agujero de seguridad.

Comment: Efectivamente, @A.Cedano. Coincido en todo lo que has dicho, especialmente en el uso de [consultas preparadas (PreparedStatement)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). La mejor manera de evitar inyección SQL y además te ayuda a localizar problemas de este tipo :)

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%c3%a9-es-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-y-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-evitarla

Comment: A las variables tipo double o int o bit (numéricos) le tienes que quitar las comillas simples.