# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "FHOLA": invalid identifier in

Tags: php, oracle

He visto varios sitios con posibles soluciones a mi problema de *Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904*, sin embargo no he tenido éxito en encontrar una solución, ¿alguien me puede ayudar a saber qué estoy haciendo mal?

Se trata de un login password en PHP que se conecta a una base de datos Oracle y me devuelve siempre el error

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "FHOLA": invalid identifier in C:\xampp\htdocs\portabilidad\php\model\loginConfig.php on line 25.
```

Este es el código del formulario HTML:

```html
<form method="post">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Username" id="user" name="user">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="pass">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-lg w-100 mt-4 mb-0" id="signinBtn" name="signinBtn">Sign in</button> 
                      <?php  
                       echo $menscript;
                      ?>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Y el código de PHP es el siguiente:

```php
include 'php/config/conexion.php';
   $menscript = "";
   #Se valida que el botón de inicio de sesión esté posteado.
   session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['signinBtn'])){
    
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $passw = $_POST['pass'];
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
  
    #Se valida que los campos de texto user & password contengan información.
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($passw)) {
      
        #Se ejecuta la consulta a la base de datos para validar al usuario y el password
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT "USUARIO",APELLIDOP,APELLIDOM,EMAIL,PERFIL
                                  FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = '.$user.'');

        #oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":user", $user);
        #oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":passw", $passw);
        $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);

        /* $results=array();
        $numrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $results, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW); */

        echo $r.'---'.$user;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Prueba con `"SELECT USUARIO, APELLIDOP, APELLIDOM, EMAIL, PERFIL FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = '$user'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advertencia**: Esta respuesta está escrita para ayudar al AP en su pregunta específica. El autor de la respuesta está consciente de la vulnerabilidad de este código ante la inyección SQL y toca ese tema al final de la respuesta.

#### Respuesta a la pregunta

El error está al construir la sentencia SQL, específicamente que estás pasando una cadena constante, pero no la estás encerrando entre comillas simples, cómo requiere el lenguaje.

Puedes comprobarlo si la colocas en una variable y la imprimes a la salida, por ejemplo:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT "USUARIO",APELLIDOP,APELLIDOM,EMAIL,PERFIL
          FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = '.$user.'';
die($sql);
```

si $user vale `'mario'`, la salida que vas a obtener es:

```sql
SELECT "USUARIO",APELLIDOP,APELLIDOM,EMAIL,PERFIL
  FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = mario
```

Por otro lado, no hace falta que pases el nombre de la columna `USUARIO` entre comillas, pues usuario no es palabra reservada, por lo que podría, por lo que la consulta podría/debiera ser:

```sql
SELECT USUARIO, APELLIDOP, APELLIDOM, EMAIL, PERFIL
  FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = 'mario'
```

Nota como `mario` está encerrado entre comillas. Siempre debieras ser capaz de copiar y pegar esta consulta en SQL*Plus o cualquier otro cliente de base de datos y ejecutarla. Si tu código no produce una consulta válida, mi sugerencia es depurar primero la consulta (solamente el SQL) y cuándo ya tengas una consulta válida, asegurarte que tu código sea capaz de producirla tal cual. Utilizando la técnica que te he presentado, puedes asegurarte de haberlo logrado y ya solo quitas el `die()` para dejar que se ejecute desde PHP.

Dado que lo que está fallando es solo lo de encerrar el valor en comillas, hay varias maneras de hacer esto en PHP, una de mis favoritas es encerrar la cadena completa en comillas dobles y utilizar nombres de variables dentro de esta cadena, que son sustituidos por el valor de la variable por el intérprete mismo, lo que evita estar escribiendo comillas simples muchas veces y es mucho más legible, así, cambiaría la asignación de construcción por:

```php
$sql = "SELECT USUARIO, APELLIDOP, APELLIDOM, EMAIL, PERFIL
          FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS 
         WHERE USUARIO = '$user'";
die($sql);
```

Y la secuencia completa por algo como:

```php
$sql = "bla, bla";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

#### No escribas código vulnerable

Sin embargo, este código es vulnerable al ataque conocido como [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Puedes y debes leer las respuestas a la pregunta [¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/21).

En resumen, utiliza consultas parametrizadas. En el código hay vestigios de un mejor intento en código comentado. Mi sugerencia es que re-escribas la consulta con parámetros, por ejemplo, esto debiera funcionar:

```php
$sql = "SELECT USUARIO, APELLIDOP, APELLIDOM, EMAIL, PERFIL
          FROM SPN_MSJ_USUARIOS 
         WHERE USUARIO = :usuario ";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":usuario", $user);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

En este caso, creamos un parámetro llamado `:usuario` y luego a ese parámetro le asignamos el valor de la variable `$user`. Dado que el cliente de base de datos sabe que esa es una *variable*, ni hacen falta las comillas y no importa lo que hayan puesto en ella, no hay manera que inyecten SQL allí.